# Feedback requested: Stack Snippets 2.0

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

Thanks to the [incredibly positive reception and great feedback on our announcement of Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), today we've shipped version 2.0. Don't know what Stack Snippets are? Just read the link above for a quick overview.

## What changed in Stack Snippets 2.0?

**A whole bunch of things**, mainly due to *your* feedback! Some of the major changes include:

- **[Editable Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315666/status-of-stack-snippets-2-0-are-snippets-now-editable/315668#315668)**: When editing a question, a link will appear below the Snippet that you can click to re-launch the Snippet editor *with your existing code*. Upon closing the editor, changes will overwrite your existing Snippet markdown.
- **[Copyable Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269771/2420979)**: Click the <kbd>Copy snippet to answer</kbd> button to "fork" a snippet to your own answer!
- **[Collapsible Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269778/2420979)**: You may now indicate whether or not to hide a Snippet when creating it. This allows you to focus on the relevant code which has changed, instead of all of the Snippet code.

A [bunch](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269779/2420979) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269831/2420979) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269902/2420979) [minor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269987/2420979) [stuff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269864/2420979) got fixed and improved, too.

## Why collapsible Snippets are important

As many people mentioned, highlighting/showcasing the difference between the posting Snippet code and the "working" or "fixed" code is essential. This just wasn't possible in the prior version of Stack Snippets. In 2.0, we feel we have a much better solution.

**Suppose that you had this Snippet in the original question (totally [my favourite one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269844/2420979) BTW):**

```js
//Made for Stack Overflow Code Testing

//Unicorn Inspired by http://drbl.in/kayh

//Made by Mr. Alien


/*
 * Just created in a hurry, so won't refactor my CSS
 * as of now, also I can drastically reduce
 * the markup but I won't do it right now
*/
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 450px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #fce300 0%, #ffc700 46%, #ff7f00 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #fce300 0%,#ffc700 46%,#ff7f00 100%);
}

.unicorn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 170px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.tail > div,
.body > div,
.leg > div,
.leg2 > div,
.leg3 > div,
.unihorn {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.tail .pone{ 
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

.tail .ptwo {
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg);
          transform: rotate(-39deg);
  top: 26px;
  left: -30px;
}

.tail .pthree {
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); 
          transform: rotate(5deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: -12px;
}

.tail .pfour {
  top: 72px;
  left: 17px;
  border-bottom: 35px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
          transform: rotate(5deg);
}

div.body .pone {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 221px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
          transform: rotate(40deg);
  top: 65px;
  left: 45px;
}

div.body .ptwo {
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(43deg);
          transform: rotate(43deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 87px;
}

div.body .pthree {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(71deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(71deg);
          transform: rotate(71deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 200px;
}

div.body .pfour {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(109deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(109deg);
          transform: rotate(109deg);
  top: 38px;
  left: 246px;
}

div.body .pfive {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  left: 310px;
  top: -27px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
}

div.body .psix {
  border-top: 85px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 319px;
  top: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .pseven {
  border-bottom: 110px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 350px;
  top: -144px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .peight {
  border-bottom: 90px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  left: 425px;
  top: -92px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
          transform: rotate(18deg);
}

div.body > div.eye {
  background-color: #000;
  top: -70px;
  left: 445px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.nose {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #f27d00;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-28deg);
          transform: rotate(-28deg);
  left: 480px;
  top: -15px;
}

div.extreme-left {
  border-top: 115px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 110px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
          transform: rotate(-65deg);
  left: 130px;
  top: 4px;
}

div.leg .pone {
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
          transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 55px;
  left: 45px; 
}

div.leg .ptwo {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 145px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          transform: rotate(-24deg);
  left: 66px;
}

div.leg .pthree {
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 33px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 164px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
  left: 63px;
}

div.leg .pfour {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 165px;
  left: 80px;
}

div.leg .pfive {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 235px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 89px;
}

div.body .extreme-right {
  left: 246px;
  top: 100px;
  border-top: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-33deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-33deg);
          transform: rotate(-33deg);
}

div.leg2 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 339px;
  top: 84px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-53deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-53deg);
          transform: rotate(-53deg);
}

div.leg2 div.ptwo {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 42px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(62deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(62deg);
          transform: rotate(62deg);
  left: 328px;
  top: 146px;
}

div.leg2 .pthree {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 154px;
  left: 368px;
}

div.leg2 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 230px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 378px;
}

div.leg3 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #ef7b00;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  left: 382px;
  top: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

div.leg3 div.ptwo {
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #e87604;
  left: 419px;
  top: 116px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-18deg);
          transform: rotate(-18deg);
}

div.leg3 div.pthree {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #e5892d;
  border-left: 13px solid transparent;
  left: 411px;
  top: 143px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-17deg);
          transform: rotate(-17deg);
}

div.leg3 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 173px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(76deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(76deg);
          transform: rotate(76deg);
  left: 403px;
}

.unihorn {
  top: -130px;
  left: 446px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-36deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-36deg);
          transform: rotate(-36deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="unicorn">
  <div class="tail">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
    <div class="psix"></div>
    <div class="pseven"></div>
    <div class="peight"></div>
    <div class="eye"></div>
    <div class="nose"></div>
    <div class="extreme-left"></div>
    <div class="extreme-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg2">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg3">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unihorn"></div>
</div>
```

**It's safe to say that this is a TON of code to display**, especially if I just want to highlight the fact that I changed the colours around a little. With collapsible snippets I can highlight just the lines I changed:

```css
html, body {
  height: 450px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #300fce 0%, #700ffc 46%, #f00ff7 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #300fce 0%,#700ffc 46%,#f00ff7 100%);
}
```

And the snippet can be expanded and run to see the net result.

```js
//Made for Stack Overflow Code Testing

//Unicorn Inspired by http://drbl.in/kayh

//Made by Mr. Alien


/*
 * Just created in a hurry, so won't refactor my CSS
 * as of now, also I can drastically reduce
 * the markup but I won't do it right now
*/
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 450px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #300fce 0%, #700ffc 46%, #f00ff7 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #300fce 0%,#700ffc 46%,#f00ff7 100%);
}

.unicorn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 170px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.tail > div,
.body > div,
.leg > div,
.leg2 > div,
.leg3 > div,
.unihorn {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.tail .pone{ 
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

.tail .ptwo {
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg);
          transform: rotate(-39deg);
  top: 26px;
  left: -30px;
}

.tail .pthree {
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); 
          transform: rotate(5deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: -12px;
}

.tail .pfour {
  top: 72px;
  left: 17px;
  border-bottom: 35px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
          transform: rotate(5deg);
}

div.body .pone {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 221px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
          transform: rotate(40deg);
  top: 65px;
  left: 45px;
}

div.body .ptwo {
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(43deg);
          transform: rotate(43deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 87px;
}

div.body .pthree {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(71deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(71deg);
          transform: rotate(71deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 200px;
}

div.body .pfour {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(109deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(109deg);
          transform: rotate(109deg);
  top: 38px;
  left: 246px;
}

div.body .pfive {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  left: 310px;
  top: -27px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
}

div.body .psix {
  border-top: 85px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 319px;
  top: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .pseven {
  border-bottom: 110px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 350px;
  top: -144px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .peight {
  border-bottom: 90px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  left: 425px;
  top: -92px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
          transform: rotate(18deg);
}

div.body > div.eye {
  background-color: #000;
  top: -70px;
  left: 445px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.nose {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #f27d00;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-28deg);
          transform: rotate(-28deg);
  left: 480px;
  top: -15px;
}

div.extreme-left {
  border-top: 115px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 110px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
          transform: rotate(-65deg);
  left: 130px;
  top: 4px;
}

div.leg .pone {
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
          transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 55px;
  left: 45px; 
}

div.leg .ptwo {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 145px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          transform: rotate(-24deg);
  left: 66px;
}

div.leg .pthree {
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 33px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 164px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
  left: 63px;
}

div.leg .pfour {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 165px;
  left: 80px;
}

div.leg .pfive {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 235px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 89px;
}

div.body .extreme-right {
  left: 246px;
  top: 100px;
  border-top: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-33deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-33deg);
          transform: rotate(-33deg);
}

div.leg2 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 339px;
  top: 84px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-53deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-53deg);
          transform: rotate(-53deg);
}

div.leg2 div.ptwo {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 42px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(62deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(62deg);
          transform: rotate(62deg);
  left: 328px;
  top: 146px;
}

div.leg2 .pthree {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 154px;
  left: 368px;
}

div.leg2 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 230px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 378px;
}

div.leg3 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #ef7b00;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  left: 382px;
  top: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

div.leg3 div.ptwo {
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #e87604;
  left: 419px;
  top: 116px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-18deg);
          transform: rotate(-18deg);
}

div.leg3 div.pthree {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #e5892d;
  border-left: 13px solid transparent;
  left: 411px;
  top: 143px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-17deg);
          transform: rotate(-17deg);
}

div.leg3 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 173px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(76deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(76deg);
          transform: rotate(76deg);
  left: 403px;
}

.unihorn {
  top: -130px;
  left: 446px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-36deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-36deg);
          transform: rotate(-36deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="unicorn">
  <div class="tail">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
    <div class="psix"></div>
    <div class="pseven"></div>
    <div class="peight"></div>
    <div class="eye"></div>
    <div class="nose"></div>
    <div class="extreme-left"></div>
    <div class="extreme-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg2">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg3">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unihorn"></div>
</div>
```

Much easier on the eyes!

## Try Stack Snippets 2.0

[Here's the sandbox for trying out the feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here). Note that Stack Snippets 2.0 is backwards compatible to the original code, so all existing demos should work properly.

Feedback is definitely welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the editor bar for the answers not showing up? I'm using Chrome, getting a console error "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" inside "snippet-javascript.en.js"

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah that's a bug. I'll push a fix momentarily. Please let me know if it then works for you.

Comment: @gunr2171 fix deployed, how about now?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. Thanks for you hard work!

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for pointing it out. I test with IE and FF locally, and of course both don't seem to care if you call `undefined.toLowerCase()` and Chrome clearly does. Damned JS lack of standards!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269899/526741 still applies.

Comment: We should have something like revision control, so a column on the left side which shows the code forks, and the revisions, say 1, 2, 3 etc.... or I can rollback to a specific revision and so on..

Comment: Still doesn't work with NoScript.  Tried whitelisting all variations of `http://stacksnippets.net/js` and `*.stackoverflow.com`. Anybody figured this out?

Comment: @BrockAdams try `https://` and see if that helps?

Comment: Is there anything planned for letting others know if the code is safe or not? For instance are we just going to be downvoting, flagging Other for answers/questions that have snippets we find "unsafe" (ie infinite loops etc), or is there going to be something like voting the snippet itself as safe/unsafe?

Comment: @Haney, (Re)tried `https://` and `^https?://` variants.  Still no-go so far.  [I know I'm not the only one experiencing this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/#comment-84672). :(

Comment: How about you prepend `NEW !` to the title. I suspect that people are thinking, *been there done that*, without seeing the version number..

Comment: Hay, somebody listens to my very negatively voted suggestions!

Comment: Thank god for the collapsible code snippets. Just trying to scroll down down the page containing this question is an exercise in futility—a great demonstration of why collapsing is so important. If only you could make the collapse link [a little less ugly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gW3oe.png) without affecting its accessibility.

Comment: It will be better if the codes are given heading like **CSS**, **html** or **javascript**. (UX)

Comment: Not sure if it's just me but it takes absolutely FOREVER to load and render the sandbox page. Also everything I've tried so far is being blocked as XSS by NoScript.

Comment: If i hide/show snippets consecutively it starts to highlight everything.

Comment: Why are jQuery, Prototype and Angular prioritized over every other library?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I would assume it's based on the popularity of the tags. jQuery, for example, has over 500k tagged questions.

Comment: @Mooseman I don't think that popularity over the years is a very good indication.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Even if you go by "Asked this week," jQuery rules the libraries with 3.1k.

Comment: What about prototype though?

Comment: Will the editing feature make it too easy for users to accidentally overwrite other people's snippets when they meant to fork them, or even simply to watch their changes take effect? I've seen a user post a fiddle of over 400 revisions, presumably because they thought they needed to save every time they wanted to run their code.

Comment: Please add a button to tidy up the code.

Comment: Awesome! It will be really useful!

Comment: `<!-- Begin snippet: js hide: true -->` that syntax is confusing. Add a comma: `<!-- Begin snippet: js, hide: true -->`.

Comment: If I have a git repository that answers the question very well, how do I point to the zip, so the server will download the zip as a backup for answers that point to git hub?  If there isn't a way to, can you build one?

Comment: Could this potentially be enabled on any site (like StackApps for example) or is this only limited to be used for Stack Overflow?

Comment: @rene there is potential for any site. We have enabled it on a few others already.

Comment: @gibberish Please stop changing the "now available" answer link. That's the best location to point to.

Comment: Creating stack snippets doesn't work using Opera 12.17 - :(

Answer (score 36):

## Feature Request

Please continue to display the "run code snippet" button even when the snippet source is collapsed.

[image: run snippet button]

I'd like to hide the implementation details and still show the demo. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270510/can-we-have-darker-code-blocks-in-blockquotes/270652#270652), for instance, has a lot of irrelevant css and html. I'd prefer if the user didn't have to click twice (once to expand and once to run) in order to run the demo.

Comment: Doesn't that risk "surprises"?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we should encourage people to just run code they haven't even looked at.

Comment: As @AnnaLear says, my concern here is I show the "brief" code as a harmless change to your original Snippet, but my hidden code is an infinite loop or some other craziness. I feel like you should have to stare at it before you run it.

Comment: @Haney if somebody wants to abuse it though, it's trivial to include an external file that _looks_ like some sort of dependency (like a JS library of some sort) but is actually malicious. It wouldn't be too hard to get code running that people haven't looked at.

Comment: You're right @nhinkle, and unfortunately this is one of the "grey areas" of this project. How do you prevent maliciousness on an open-ended tool? Detecting it is difficult for the exact reason you just stated. So we have to trust the community to downvote bad Snippets. Additionally, HTML 5 iframe sandboxing helps to protect the user.

Comment: @Haney It could be a rep based privilege on the grounds that someone who has invested the time and effort to get to, say, 10k is unlikely to want to risk suspension by abusing this.

Comment: @MartinSmith Since this has to be based off the privilege of the snippet's author rather than the viewer, that kind of rep-based unlock is unfortunately likely to cause more confusion with the majority than anything. "Why does this snippet have a run button and this one doesn't?" kind of thing.

Comment: +1 from me. I'm not going to read the code before running anyway. Especially if they make the code nice and long. (which is the whole point of collapsible snippets)

Comment: @canon Sure. We still don't need to be implicitly encouraging people to click before looking.

Comment: I ran the Unicorn example without actually inspecting it.

Comment: @canon I think I already explained the entirety of my argument. We aren't jsFiddle so we might do some things differently. In the end, it's not me you need to convince, it's Haney. The only thing I have a strong objection to here is making this privilege-based.

Comment: Provide a big hammer for the "oh crap! This snippet is stealing SE cookies and posting copies of itself all over SE" situation.
This hammer needs to prevent the snippet content from being sent to browsers, period.  When designing this hammer, keep in mind that your real enemy is a specially crafted snippet which can take over the user's browser when they *merely* view the page, ie, a snippet that contains an unpatched exploit.
I recommend a "show content as text anyway" button. We're grownups.

Comment: I agree with the request here. The concerns are valid, too, but in balance I think the community will police this well, especially if there is a flag specific to "has malicious code snippet"

Comment: This is bad idea. I am sure surprises will happen even now. You don't know people man. Many invest a lot of effort to get their account hacked, much more than just clicking a button.

Comment: @TomášZato are you referring to some cross-domain, sandboxed iframe exploit I'm unaware of?

Comment: @canon I'm not sure what the options are and frankly I didn't realize the iframe is actually sandboxed.

Comment: +1 But for my purposes, I'd like to be able to selectively hide the (bulky and not terribly interesting) HTML and CSS and just show the relevant JS code - while keeping the RUN button displayed. In other words have three independent hide buttons in the editor: Hide HTML, Hide CSS, and Hide JS.

Answer (score 30):

So apparently this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in the next build. Thanks everyone who supported the feature request.

---

**Feature request:**

Don't prioritize Angular, jQuery and Prototype above other libraries. Instead, let users select from a wider selection of libraries. Even if we ignore how unpopular Prototype already *is*, there are a lot of questions about React, Knockout, Ember, D3, Q and a whole bunch of other stuff.

For the very least - I think the 50 most popular libraries should be included, unless we're going to allow 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I'm definitely not against this, but I'm also a pretty crappy designer in terms of UI. Anyone got a recommendation on HOW to stuff 50 or so libs into the editor in a way that doesn't suck?

Comment: @Haney Maybe some sort of two-level select: 1) Select library: jQuery/Angular/etc. 2) Select version: v1/2/3... Also thinking it might be useful to have an "Other" option that takes a URL and just inserts a <script> tag, since a lot of people don't quite get that you can add anything you want this way.

Comment: @DavidFullerton I like this other idea. I don't like having 50 hard-coded versions of 50 libs in the app because I see it becoming maintenance hell with posts like "Why doesn't Snippets have the latest jQuery version?" and so on. Maybe we move to JUST other insert? I like that idea a lot.

Comment: @Haney having quick select options for the most common libraries makes life a lot easier for users, so I think there should be *some* built-in stuff. But if you have an "other" option, you can probably get away with just a handful of libraries.

Comment: @DavidFullerton exactly. My goal is to dodge having to update this every other day for a new version of a lib. I might refine the lib selection to more common stuff perhaps. Take out Prototype, add in React, KnockOut, Ember, etc.

Comment: @Haney as for adding lots of libraries in a way that doesn't suck. You already have that mechanism, the tag system. Also, while on that line of thought, it would be nice to automatically include libraries that match tags for known libraries (i.e. snippets on questions tagged [tag:jquery] should by default include jQuery).

Comment: @Haney I think what JSFiddle does in this case is very reasonable, they let you select from the common ones but then also include third party libraries. Just remember that there is a lot of room for abuse with third party libraries since they run code the user doesn't directly see (JSFiddle is banned on Facebook for example) so it should probably be a privilege that requires some amount of rep.

Comment: I have integrated a button for easily adding third party JS and CSS files! It'll go live in the next build.

Comment: security implications of loading arbitrary script files?

Comment: @RobertLevy in my opinion they should be privileged (as in - require X rep) but remember that the potential for mischeif isn't too high anyway since it's all run in an iframe.

Comment: Requiring rep or not, can we have some kind of warning that a snippet requires an external library before running it (either some sort of obvious notation, or a msgbox)?

Comment: @Haney: An autocompleter along the lines of select2 or typeahead or a dozen others: A small text box which, on focus, gets a drop-down under it of all the standard libs (very long list). Typing in the box filters the list. E.g., I know I want jQuery, so I type "jq" and that narrows the drop-down list to anything containing "jq". Or I know I want d3, so I type "d3", and... This is both more useful and less real estate. Choosing one could add it (like a tag) with an [x] to remove it.

Answer (score 23):

Disclaimer: My photo editing skills are pathetic: this is the best i could come up with in order to explain the features i wish to see in Stack Snippet, as well as to address few feature requests by other users (*and yes i admit that it's a bit [jsfiddlish](http://jsfiddle.net/))*.

**TL;DR:**

My Stack Snippet window will probably look familiar to the following once it has all the features mentioned below:

> [image]

---

The current implementation seems to have addressed many previous requests. Still:

- *Show/Hide code Snippet* option doesn't actually solve
  the problem of having to scroll through all the **irrelevant** code. Still user has
  to scroll to the bottom of entire the code to view the
  result. [Related Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270959/2333214) [Related Request @ MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239501/256148)
- The user have to edit the post or click <kbd>Copy snippet to answer</kbd> and then click <kbd>Edit the above snippet</kbd> in order to just launch the code in Stack Snippet Editor. Related [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271746/2333214)
- Some libraries seems to have given too much importance by having individual dropdowns for each, this also unnecessarily consumes space in the UI. [Related Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271030/2333214)
- Most of the online editors use *external library* option to keep the `HTML` tidy & readable. Currently, The links to libraries are visible in `HTML` block and needs to be removed manually. This decreases the readability of `HTML` and kind of questions the need for the <kbd>external library</kbd> button in `UI`.

  Also, displaying the `<link>` along with the content of `<body>` will
  be misleading for beginners, since the best practice is to include
  `<link>` inside `<head>`, as mentioned by Dan in this [Related
  Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271648/2333214) which also suggests a different UI to approach
  this issue
- No option for switching to *full Page* view from the stack Snippet editor
- The *Hide Snippet By Default* checkbox and 3 tiny buttons consumes too much unnecessary space in UI:

> [image]

---

**Following are my suggestions to address these issues along with feature requests:**

Have an option to display the most relevant piece of code, by hiding the unnecessary parts using a comment such as `<!-- Hide code snippet -->` as requested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269782/2333214). (*a* <kbd>Hide  Selected</kbd> *button that hides the selected content by adding respective comments in each language will be great!*)

Below the relevant code , have the following instead of the *Show/Hide code Snippet* option:

> [image]

(*Clicking the first two buttons will tun them into* <kbd>Hide Results</kbd> *and* <kbd>Hide Full Code</kbd> *respectively.*)

- The <kbd>Display Result</kbd> button will directly display the result below, Addresses this [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270959/2333214) as well as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271762/2333214).
- The <kbd>Display Full Code</kbd> button will reveal the code hidden by `<!-- Hide code snippet -->`
- The <kbd>Edit Snippet</kbd> button will open the snippet in Stack Snippet window. Addresses this [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271746/2333214)

---

Once the Stack Snippet window is launched, User will be able to perform the following actions:

### 1. Select External Libraries (*if required*)

> - 1.1 Select the external library using an autocomplete textbox<sup>1</sup>. If it
>     is unavailable goto 1.3. addresses this [Feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271030/2333214) as well as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270973/2333214). Suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271731/2333214)
> - 1.2 If different versions of the selected library is found, display a dropdown which allows the user to choose the desired version.
> - 1.3 Add an external link to the required library
> - 1.4 Remove the added libraries if not required

### 2. Adjust the interface

> - 2.1 **Close the unwanted windows:**
>     The user might not be always working with all 3  languages
>     (*HTML,CSS,JS*). It'll be nice to have an option to close unwanted
>     windows to utilize the space.
> - 2.2 **Resize the windows accordingly:**
>
>   In many CSS *responsive* questions, the default size of the result
>     window or the *full page* view might not be sufficient to view or
>     solve the problem. The layout might be breaking in between these. Related [feature request @ MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239638/make-code-snippets-results-window-vertically-resizable)

### 3. <del>Tidy Up the Code (*Please !*)</del> (*This one is implemented :*)

> Already requested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269803/2333214)

### 4.  <kbd>Run</kbd> the *tidy* - Code.

> If everything is fine, goto step 6, if **everything** is broke, goto
>   step5

### 5. <kbd>Reset</kbd> the entire stuff.

> ( *Since I even broke whatever was already working?  [image: :D]* )

### 6. Choose The Display Options

> - 6.1 Choose whether to display the code in post.
>
>   The code will be hidden by default, as [requested here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270994/2333214). (*The default state could be decided based on the presence of `<!-- hide code snippet -->` comment, total length of the snippet etc as well, upto the community*)
> - 6.2 Choose whether to display the result in *Full Page* view while clicking the <kbd>Display Result</kbd> button.
>
>   This will be particularly helpful in many CSS related questions
>     where the layout can be properly seen only in fullscreen. [Here is an Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22296568/2333214)

### 7. Complete/Submit The Stack Snippet

> - 7.1 <kbd>Insert Into Post</kbd>:
>
>   This option will either open the corresponding post in edit view (*If it is not already in edit view*)  or directly edit the post the user is currently working
>     with. Whichever majority of the community prefers.
>
>   > If the later, Edits from users having <2000 rep, goes to the [Suggested
>   >     Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) review queue.
> - 7.2 <kbd>Fork Into Answer</kbd>:
>
>   Similar to the existing <kbd>Copy snippet to answer</kbd> option, but inside the editor, and will be visible only if the user playing with the snippet
>     is not it's creator.
>     (*Really, Why Am i currently shown an option to fork my own
>     snippet to another answer? ideally i should update my existing
>     answer.*)

### 8. View The Result In Full Page view

### 9. Intercept Console.log!

> Related [Feature Request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271658/2333214), [Feature Request @ MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets) if the community wants it. Else just expand the sidebar! :)
>
> this can be achieved now by adding the following script (*thanks to tj crowder*):
>
> ```
>   <script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
> ```
>
> usage: `snippet.log(msg);`  [(demo answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344672/2333214)

**Update**

The <kbd>Full page</kbd> button in post [is hiding the results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26072041/2333214) as shown below:

[image]

Would be better if it is moved to the *menu bar* above (*We've plenty of space there*):

> [image]

Or even better, just an icon with a tooltip:

> [image]

---

*P.S:* If you haven't noticed, The color scheme in image is used intentionally; The existing color scheme is still metaish. Please add some orange here and there :)

<sup>1</sup> The source of autocomplete could be the existing [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) wiki's for the libraries and plugins. There should be an option to 
insert *special* external link to libraries (*Maybe a privilege*), something like

> ```
> [Version 1][CDN:1.0]
>
> [Version 2][CDN:2.0]
>
>
> [CDN:1.0]: http://path to version 1
>
> [CDN:2.0]: http://path to version 2
> ```

Which will be maintained by the community, protected by the the review queues.

Answer (score 18):

> **Update:** This bug has been fixed!

---

Got another potential bug.

> [image]

Notice how the "Html" label is hidden behind the scroll bar. This is not causing any functional problems as far as I can see, but looks wrong.

This seems to be the case for any of the quadrants that have a scroll bar.

I'm using Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m, and there are no console/javascript errors.

Comment: Good one. I'll move those out a few pixels to provide a buffer. That'll go live in an "eventual" build over the next few days vs ASAP since it isn't destroying anything.

Comment: Fixed and will be live in the next build.

Answer (score 13):

## I'd say let it roll!

Time for real-world testing before we make any major changes, IMO.

---

Though I would change the words No jQuery to ***--use jQuery--***

Seriously though, use something besides the word <sub>No No No No</sub> :)

```css
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf81d.png"/>
```

Comment: I like this one. I'll be changing it up tomorrow. ;)

Comment: -1, I like the explicit `No`. (and it seems to encourage native JS :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I'll wait for more votes to decide what it should be.

Comment: I think like @Bergi, but I think that showing something like **--jQuery: off--** (or `--jQuery: version_number--` when turned on) could be a reasonable compromise, because it does not encourage the people to use jQuery and does still sound better than "No jQuery".

Comment: @Theolodis' `--jQuery: off--` makes the most sense.  The problem with replacing the default values with `--use jQuery--` is that, once you click on the dropdown, it doesn't make sense that "use jQuery" is the option you select to *not* use jQuery.

Comment: @AmeliaBR also that. But it does also ask the user to "**use jQuery**", which I wouldn't recommend either.

Comment: I'm gonna be honest, I don't think the naming/phrasing of the drop downs matters that much in the long run. There are pros and cons to each approach, so for now I plan to leave as-is. Gotta pick my battles. :)

Answer (score 11):

Rename "Fullscreen" to something else as it really doesn't fill my computer screen.

Also, could you push onto the history state so the back button will close "fullscreen"?

I also noted this on George's show/hide snippet - the dotted border seems to carry across the chevron.

[image]

And the icon seems too bright in the toolbar for meta.

Comment: Perhaps "Full page"?

Comment: Changed to "Full page". I don't plan to mess with the history stack because I fundamentally do not believe in altering the history of a browser. Additionally, it isn't uniformly supported and might create confusing / an inconsistent experience.

Comment: Hitting `Esc` would be a more standard way of exiting fullscreen.

Comment: As for the toolbar icon, I believe that that is what it will look like on the main site and that that design is just being used here to demonstrate what it will look like there.

Answer (score 10):

**Feature Request:**

I think that hiding a snipped by default when posting is good, but it would even better if I, the user, could choose to hide all snippets by default.

**Why?** Well, basically because I see the case where someone does post a ton of code in a snipped that is not hidden by default, and I'll have to scroll to either edit if it was not legit, or see the answers/other answers - Much scroll, no time.

Answer (score 8):

Looking good.  One little annoyance (and this is something that always bugs me with JSFiddle, too):

The auto-indenting feature over-rides the correct indentation pattern for multi-line function chains in Javascript.

E.g., when I [type the following](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270977/3128209):

```js
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
           .data(function(d,i){ return d3.range(0,255); });
```

As soon as I type a `{`, the second line gets pushed flush-left.  I fix it, and then get to the `}`, and it happens again.   ***Urgh.***

This is a common code pattern in d3 and JQuery, so it would be nice if the auto-indenting algorithm recognized that a line starting with `.` is a wrap-around from the previous line, and should be indented.

Of course, how *much* it should be indented is a matter of debate; some people always use a standard two-space indent, I tend to align it with a `.` on the previous line.  [Mike Bostock's introduction to d3](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/#chaining) advises:

> The recommended indentation pattern for method chaining is four spaces for methods that preserve the current selection and two spaces for methods that change the selection.

...which isn't exactly something a general purpose code-tidying algorithm is going to determine.  Can you instead just turn off the auto-indenting function for lines that start with `.`?

Comment: or don't auto-indent if I pressed <kbd>Shift+enter</kbd>

Comment: ...or just don't auto indent at all, please.

Comment: @DJDavid98: That looks like the plan for now, according to Haney's [response to my post on the sandbox](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270977/3128209); he suggested that it might eventually be an option that you could turn on or off.

Answer (score 8):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), as per the comment.

---

Probably a tiny thing, but if someone has added an external library, it would be nice if it indicated that when re-editing an existing snippet.

As of right now, anytime you load the editor, you will always get "No jQuery", "No D3", "No Knockout", and "No AngularJS" even if it has already loaded those libraries.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I bet I can make this happen. Stand by for potential progress!

Comment: Patched this up and it should work in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

## Automatic slow/bad code warning system

I disagree with the entire safety system, voting as safe, etc. idea, as this puts extra load on the user whilst there is already a system in place where users can manually provide such feedback. However queuing a callback after 15 seconds which checks whether at most 20 seconds have past and gives a "green light" call to SO.com if it was quick enough. If at least 75% of the "Runs" (and minimally 5 runs) did not trigger this ajax call this will automatically trigger a warning message. After all realistically the only type of 'malicious' code in JavaScript nowadays is code that either crashes your tab or makes it run infinitely slow. Oh well, just an idea, vote with your votes :D .

Just thinking, there's an even better way to do this possibly with WebWorkers which will only report back if the code is slow. That would however not catch crashes, still worth testing out maybe.

Comment: Although you certainly have a point, I'm afraid deciding on the 'how long does it have to take to be slow' and 'how often does it need to be slow to be flagged' will make this an ambiguous feature.

Comment: Ambiguous features are however not bad features. This feature tries to quantify a realistic concern the community has. People who disagree can still run the code, but an advance warning is always nice. You can always just show the average execution time instead alternatively, though I personally would find that less beautiful UX technically as it adds extra load on the user.

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit late for a feature request on the awesome running stack snippet but anyway :

Am I the only one to read *HTML* code first then the related *CSS* and read *JS* code at the end? In the stack snippet,*JS* code is displayed first then *CSS* and *HTML* last.

**Could they be displayed the other way around?**

like this :
**HTML

CSS

JS**

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269838/2333214

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240199/show-snippet-components-in-the-same-order-theyre-included-when-running

Answer (score 4):

### Feature Request - Intercept `console.log()`

Sometimes a question is all JavaScript and not HTML.  If you want to just display the output of an expression, it is easy to say `console.log(myValue)`.  But, that isn't visible on the page.  To get the output on the page, we are stuck with something like `document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myValue))`.

It would be nice if, within a runnable snippet, `console.log()` was intercepted and redirected to somewhere visible on the page. You could inject a custom `console` object into the running context:

```js
var console = {
    log: function(s) {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
    }
};

console.log("Look at me!");
```

Or, expose a `print()` function that does the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried `document.write()`? If not, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Haney - Yes, `document.write()` works ok.  Still, there are cases where you can't use `document.write()`, and it might be nice to have access to a visible console.

Comment: I hear you. It's definitely a thought. I'll give it some thinking and see what I can imagine. Or, if you envision something, show me! :)

Comment: @Haney Here's a [demo](http://antisanity.net/snippet-demo/). It requires you to nest the snippet another frame deeper so the console doesn't pollute its DOM. Even so, you'd need to inject a `<script>window.parent.attachConsole()</script>`. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273249/621962).

Comment: This one is implemented: `snippet.log()` :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets

Comment: @TJ Really? It [doesn't for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/259693).

Comment: @Scimonster http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831914/2333214

Comment: @TJ Only by including the script, but OK.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty please:

## Make it harder for newbies to post snippets by mistake

Clearly, the `<>` icon is misleading -- it looks a lot like the "I want to post some code" icon in many other on-line editors, while the `{}` looks to me like, uh, I dunno, JSON?  Maybe just switching the order of the icons would already help.

The big slow multi-pane editor window must also be incredibly confusing when you click it by mistake.

Maybe disable this feature in tags where it has been predominantly used by mistake?  Some quick querying should indicate where a large amount of posted snippets in a tag have been posted by low-rep users and removed by high-rep users.

Answer (score 3):

Just reconfirming the bug noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers?page=2&tab=active#comment87602_269776) and confirmed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270251/256431): specifically, if the post is greyed out, when you go Fullscreen the rest of the Q&A is still visible and <strike>mostly</strike> somewhat still interactive.

Comment: Fixed this by disabling heavily downvoted Snippets, which also gives users control over disabling malicious snippets.

Comment: @Haney That seemed like an overkill, but it is still only one more click to edit the post first, then the code can be run again, so I'm happy with that.

Comment: Mark - it might be "overkill" but it adds a layer of user-controlled security. Snippet is malicious? Downvote it and it becomes un-runnable. Best option we could come up with after discussions.

Comment: @Haney I think a better option would be a message saying it's disabled due to low score *but with a button to run it anyway*. Actually *malicious* posts should get deleted by flags before too long (average is probably 10 minutes or so). This doesn't put control of snippet running in the hands of users so much as the mob, writ large.

Answer (score 3):

## Show editor/playgroud instead of all code in blocks in the post itself

Rather than collapsing the code, and then showing the full code below each other, why not just show the editor itself with the code loaded and the result loaded in one of the frames. One of the great things about jsFiddle is that the user can change stuff around and thus learn how the code works exactly. This playground aspect is a huge part of the reason why jsFiddles are so useful. Possibly allow the code author to choose whether he wants to inline it in his post or just fire up the editor/playground.

Comment: I  love the way how the results are shown inline in the post rather than showing me a popup or taking me to a new tab... i'd prefer an *Edit* or *Play* buttons instead to load the editor/playground... it's just one click for the playboys...

Answer (score 3):

## Feature Request

Please allow us to set a line-number to auto-scroll long snippets to the pertinent section of code, i.e.:

```
<!-- language: lang-js, line: 42 -->
```

In [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26064389/621962), there's a large object literal that the rest of the code is dependent upon. In order to ensure that the important part of the code wasn't hidden beyond the scroll-height, I stringified the object and tucked it into an `<input type="hidden">`. That seems hackish. I'd prefer to have that object literal, nicely formatted, at the beginning of my code. I'd just like to skip past it initially in order to highlight the important stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider having a way to play with existing snippets in the snippet editor, with a single click--without having to click "edit" on the post and then "edit the above snippet".

I only want to play with it! I don't want to edit their post or create a new answer!

Stack Snippets is an excellent new feature.

Answer (score 1):

What! **No [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)**? Not even an empty menu [reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270972/313192) "`No Dojo`"? Why is my favorite toolkit left out of the love?

All snark aside, it would be really nice to see more toolkits supported, and Dojo is [an important one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dojo). <strike>Judging from the number of questions, it's also less confusing to people [than jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).</strike> (Oops, this was supposed to be the no-snark paragraph.)

Comment: I have no argument as to Dojo being important. I just picked 4 popular libs somewhat in passing. I have added a new external library button that allows you to easily add external JS or CSS files to your snippet. I've also replaced Prototype with Knockout.

Answer (score 1):

So I noticed something, and I'm not sure it's a huge deal, but wanted to point it out anyway. In the sandbox for snippets, one of the answers is downvoted due to the poster wanting to test something. They've edited a couple times.

Their answer no longer has a runnable snippet, something people were asking for, which is great! What I noticed, however, is in the revision history, the snippet is still playable.

Here's some screenshots of what I mean:

> [image: Answer]

And the revision history:

> [image: Revision showing play button]
>   [image: Revision being played]

While I don't think it's a huge issue, I thought it'd be good to point it out.

Comment: Definitely good to point out. Not sure of a way around that to be honest. Would have to consider it for a bit. :)

Comment: Would it be easy to make snippets not runnable in the history period? I don't know how easy/hard that would be, but it would definitely prevent this, or someone editing a potential browser-crashing snippet to a fixed version, and someone else running it in revision.

Comment: I enabled them in revision history as I was asked to do so. I will see if I can do something to disable them if the post is downvoted perhaps?

Comment: Sounds good- I didn't know someone had asked for that specifically. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Feature Requests

I am a great fan of Stack Snippets, and plan to use it now in most of my answers. There are a few things that will make life easier when answering questions - particularly Twitter Bootstrap, d3.js or ajax-related ones:

1. Additional Libraries

I have seen the first answer, and just want to lend my voice to ask for more 3rd party libraries - particularly JQuery-UI and Twitter-Bootstrap as external library drop-downs. I noticed Bootstrap has now been added as a selectable option to JSFiddle when you select the latest JQuery version.

2. Adding data files to the snippet

One advantage to [Plunker](http://plnk.co) is the ability to add files like JSON, XML or TXT files that can be accessed in the JavaScript code. This is particularly useful for d3.js answers.
This allows you to replicate the code from d3 questions as it loads data files from the server, rather than having to rewrite JavaScript to use variables to load in the data.

3. Ajax-friendly snippets

The number of ajax-tagged questions, as of this request, is over 100K on Stackoverflow.
For mocking up ajax issues, JS Fiddle offers [echo functionality](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).
I personally have been using [mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/) to mock up ajax  responses when trying to recreate ajax-related problems. It would be cool if Stackoverflow could offer a similar capability for someone creating a snippet to add a similar mockup response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fit hundreds of external libraries into a pretty UI:  Make the external resource textbox autocomplete like codepen.io does.  IMHO it's actually easier to use an autocompleting text box than a dropdown of even modest length.

Answer (score -4):

## Suggestions/Feature Requests

- **Allow a safety review or rating for snippets:** That way, those that run the snippet can mark it as stable/safe etc. or have some numerical rating system. It would reward those that make sure their code is at least not crashy (if it is, you can always just use a code block instead), encourage checking the code carefully before the question is posted and it would provide a quick and easy indicator that would help avoid bad code, for at least those that follow the first few that visit the question and run the code. *Alternatively, being able to flag snippets for bad performance/crashyness/safety would probably also work fine*.

*(edit: as canon suggested in the comments, this **should** be per version of the snippet, perhaps keeping 1 undo to make sure mistakes aren't punished by clearing the entire rating; the same system that works for post revisions should work for this as well)*

*(edit: l4mpi in the comments makes a good case for why this would be redundant (ratings/flagging for snippets). Although I'm now less convinced ratings/flagging would be a good idea, I'll leave it here for now, to make the discussion in the comments clearer.)*

- **Have a "number of runs" counter** and perhaps even show which users have run the specific snippet (if the snippet changes, clear the counter and information on runs). This could work as a less secure alternative to a review and would also prevent claims that "it doesn't work" if someone hasn't even run the code (although this is quite rare and might be disruptive - just thinking out loud).
- **Titles and descriptions for snippets:** This would not only make clear what the snippet is and what it's supposed to do (while being collapsible with the rest of the snippet, at least the description) and would also prepare the system for a possible future indexing of snippets on SO, so that it would be possible to have a searchable database of snippets (with ratings, at least for safety), with links to the questions they come from. It could make SO much, much more potent for the developer community and it would be wise, if that ever is a plan, to have titling from the start, so old snippets aren't left in an anonymous and unrecognizable state without someone having to look them over again.
- **Preferences for snippets**: Such as, auto-collapse or auto-expand by default and, if in the future embedding is the solution of choice, auto-executing the embed or just presenting a button to do it manually (and prevent extra-long loading times and wasting of server resources).

### Why embedding is better

First of all, I suggest embedding `jsFiddle` and other engines with a fallback to the StackSnippets system. That way, downtime is less of an issue. Also, embedding will allow SO to much faster and much more efficiently add support for languages and take advantages of all the web software and engines *already available* and the work that has been put into them. As suggested above, ideally these embeds would not load automatically by default.

What I'm thinking of is, a StackSnippet element that `POST`s the code from the snippet to `jsFiddle` or something else and embeds the returned page. I feel that embedding is what makes overall much more software design sense and the possible disadvantages are fewer than what a fully SO-dependent StackSnippets system would have. Also, it is in agreement with the community-modded model of StackExchange in general - like community modding, the website grows with its community. Likewise, with embeds, the StackSnippets system would grow with the development tools and popularity of them, not depending on specific StackOverflow initiatives (which are fine, but I think embedding is *much* more beneficial in the long-term).

*(edit: an additional advantage would be to attach API `POST`s to other engines as well. Instead of having snippets runnable with just StackSnippets or `jsFiddle`, other alternatives would be easy to add such as `CodePen`, providing further redundancy through existing infrastructure.)*

If embedding means making deals with websites, I think that's fine. It can be done incrementally and sites like `jsFiddle` and `regex101` have helped SO so much, it's only fair (if economically viable of course) to return the favor with explicit cooperation.

Comment: I like the safety rating idea a lot. Could potentially tie it in to a rep bonus/punishment, but that may give a way for people to exploit the system.

Comment: @TomHart How would a rep system for snippets, on a website that already has one that works, be more exploitable than the already existing rep system? Note that I'm not recommending a rep system, I feel it would be redundant, but I do think that a minimal safety rating would work smoothly enough. Now that I think of it, flagging could also work well.

Comment: It was just an idea, to backup how safe the snippet (is/should) be. As far as exploiting I was thinking maybe people would start writing snippets where they're not really necessary just for the rep. It was just a passing thought, but seems a tad overkill/just pointless haha.

Comment: @TomHart I might have come off as more hard than I intended :P Didn't mean to be _that_ critical, just using your idea as an excuse to further argue in favor of my own and perhaps _some day_, take over the world.

Comment: Haha it's okay, I was kinda just typing as I was thinking, but again to reiterate, I think the safety idea or yours is a great idea :).

Comment: @canon __1.__ Agreed 100% on per-version ratings; I had this in the count suggestion but it makes perfect sense here as well. I don't understand how it could be gamed and I don't understand what you mean on user recovery. The way I see it the security rating isn't a _code quality_ rating, just a warning to prevent problems in the future. If there is a _known_ severe bug, it can just be a code listing instead. __2.__ why exclude them? The idea for me is to provide some metric of how much the snippet has been tested. If you _need_ to exclude them, use the same system used for views on questions.

Comment: @canon ah ok, that makes more sense. I just added an edit, where I mention that the same versioning system for posts can be used for snippets, thus allowing backtracking to restore the rating, if there is such malice. In any case, the same can happen with questions and SO seems to be doing fine :P

Comment: @canon btw, on embedding, I think that my suggestion has a possible solution for that (if the problem is stability as the post you linked states): Store the snippet on StackOverflow and the embed is just a `POST` to the API of whatever web app is to be embedded, essentially creating a temporary `jsFiddle` in our case. If `jsFiddle` is down, it falls back to the built-in Snippet engine on StackOverflow. This would require less storage on the side of `jsFiddle` and other engines as well.

Comment: @canon perhaps, but still, unless we consider the rep system broken and requiring changes, this should also be fine in the same sense. Its practically the same system, even the same infrastructure could be used if it's generalized enough. On the side of social mechanics, it should work just as well (no matter how broken the rep system may be) - also, there is the case of having a snippet downvoted to hell in a highly rated question, which provides more resistance to trollish downvoting in my opinion (but this is of course, speculation).

Comment: "Allow a safety review or rating for snippets" - We already have that, it's called voting and commenting. Downvote and optionally comment on posts with snippets that contain bad code, just like you would when the code in question is _not_ in a snippet but simply in a code block. Adding extra functionality which only exists for code snippets would only complicate things.

Comment: @l4mpi It would complicate things, but in my opinion, there is a usability difference between code listings and runnable snippets. Nobody bats an eye at clicking on a linked fiddle, so why would people not just run snippets blindly? I also added that flagging would work just as well, which would be much less complicated (I'd be interested in what your opinion is on that, as an alternative).

Comment: @canon If we have both, we can have our pie and eat it too. StackSnippets would not have to have the full feature set of `jsFiddle`, could be used only as a fallback, while maintaining use of `jsFiddle` overall, which I think is best as it is a tool specialized in that job, whereas StackSnippets in part of a larger structure. If having both isn't beneficial, why then have StackSnippets in the first place? The same logic can be applied. My idea is to make them complement each other, rather than have StackSnippets replace `jsFiddle` entirely.

Comment: @canon well I was just elaborating on the theoretical benefits, but to be specific, it can, just not in 100% of cases, which is fine by me, for a backup. jsFiddle has support for Coffeescript, SCSS, AJAX, jsHint, jsTidy, sharing, collaboration, accounts, DTDs, document load events and a cornucopia of libraries. These aren't useless, but the vast majority of fiddles don't use them. StackSnippets can add support slowly and carefully, based on feedback which would be based on usage, while having jsFiddle cover it in the meanwhile. Would StackSnippets even have all those from the start?

Comment: @ivy_lynx so, what do you currently do when a post contains a link to a jsfiddle which is unsafe, bad, or just generally disagreeable? Simply _do the exact same thing for a post that contains a Stack Snippet which is unsafe, bad, etc_. Flagging should be reserved for extreme cases, e.g. a snippet purposefully written for crashing a users browser (or making it unresponsive) should be flagged with a custom flag explaining the issue. A snippet that makes the browser unresponsive because it's bad code should simply be downvoted and commented on - mod time is too valuable to handle cases like that.

Comment: @canon on your edit: we'd only have to save to jsFiddle what StackSnippets _can't_ handle itself. I don't see that as pointless.

Comment: @l4mpi I didn't think of it like that and it seems more elegant to not have separate systems indeed. A lot of people have expressed reservations for the security of this - perhaps this comparison should be made in this case.

Comment: @canon yeah but inclusions are easy, what about all the other features? I'm not arguing they're extremely useful (except AJAX handling) but they still are "features" and not bloat if you're doing more than a snippet.