# Stack Snippets console output

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

**TL;DR: see UPDATE#3**

I recently answered a Stack Overflow question and inserted a stack snippet for a quick demo of my solution.
However, it was a simple JavaScript-only related problem and I didn't use any other panels (HTML/CSS) and the result was the classic `console.log(result)`.
I was wondering if there should be some kind of API to present the console output in the snippet results panel (where only HTML is viewable now).

Let's say you have a solution for a `sum` function and you write it in a stack snippet like this one:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log('1 + 2 = ' + sum(1, 2));
```

The code is working, but the snippet isn't useful at all because the result is not shown on the result panel (it acts like a static code block).

Sure one could've written the snippet as this:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

showResult('1 + 2 = ' + sum(1, 2));


// helper function
function showResult(result) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

But I think that it defeats the purpose of the snippet: to make it *easier* for the users to insert and see the results of the solution.

So what do you think? Should I just open my console in order to see all the complete stack snippet outputs or is there a need of some kind of console API for the stack snippets too?

## Update:

After several months after I recently added this question, while I really wanted to see the the reaction of SO's community on this topic, it became clear that there isn't going to be a fast decision taken by the SO team.
Therefore, in my opinion, currently, the best solution is the one described in [Sam's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273049/stack-snippets-console-output/289618#answer-273125). With this approach you are able to show both dom and console outputs in separate panels without having to alter your code to implement this kind of separation. Of course there is the downside of that you have to include and rely on a 3rd party tool (such as firebug lite), but it seems to be a minor cost if you consider the result.

To explain my decision, I would have been OK with having the user to just check the browser's native console if he had the opportunity to only open the console for the targeted stack snippet. But since you can't and opening the console can show multiple different things that do not have anything to do with the stack snippets (it can show logs, errors or any other kind of messages from the parent window and from other sibling frames), I consider that this approach would actually make the user more confused about the result of the code.

I will keep my eyes opened and will post updates and possibly accept different answers as time passes and new ideas/tools emerge on this topic, but for now, having firebug lite or any similar tool is the way to go.

## Update #2:

It seems that a snippets *competitor* (if I can name it like this in this context) has recently implemented this feature: https://blog.codepen.io/2016/01/27/new-feature-javascript-console/ .
If codepen, which is a massive player in this field, decided to have a custom console for the same reasons, it kind of validates my original needs for the console in stack snippets.

## Update #3:

It seems that SO implemented a virtual console feature in the code snippets that actually let the user see a simple `console.log` output in the result pane.
In [this crosspost on meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets) you can see the answer regarding this exact feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279419/163555 .

Comment: I started using `alert()` in stack snippets. It ain't pretty, but it works. It would be nice if SO would (optionally?) catch the console output and display that in the snippet, though.

Comment: It may be fit for a simple solution as the one in my question, but something tells me that opening a modal popup is not the way to go... Imagine some kind of animation callbacks logs.. they would freeze the whole js execution thread and they might be too many to handle.

Comment: Yea, the `alert` is just a workaround right now.

Comment: the snippet that I uses is `var log = (function () {
    var $log = $('#log');
    return function (msg) {
        $('<p/>', {text: msg}).prependTo($log)
    }
})();
`

Comment: I don't understand why [@artjom-b's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b) answer has so many down-votes??? The result pane is your DOM not the console (unless you started customizing the result pane based on the snippet language or something). What is wrong with explaining that `console.log` output can be viewed through the browsers dev tools if the OP is new to web development?

Comment: Nitpicking, but `getElementById` because ID, and because it's WAY faster than `querySelector`. :D

Comment: Also wouldn't outputting `console.log` to the result pane confuse the OP further? If you really want to output `console.log` as DOM content then use [@jeroen's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/419956/jeroen) [method](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273121/692942) - `console.log = function(x) { document.write(x + "<br />"); };` or just `document.write` even (less confusing in terms of what to expect in each case).

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets

Comment: document.body.innerHTML = 'stuff'; the html, head, and body tags are included by default. If I'm going to be doing it multiple times in a snippet, I'll define a function to make it cleaner.

Comment: I'd just like to add that, if Stack Exchange does implement something like this, please wrap the native `console.log` instead of just replacing it. The native functions are getting more featureful over time (custom formatters coming soon!) and we wouldn't want to break examples of those.

Comment: @JeremyBanks [my implementation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273249/621962) wraps, fyi. ;)

Comment: Should you put an update at the top of the question that mentions this is done? SO now includes console output by default. Well, let me rephrase that. New snippets have console output by default by having a `console: true` flag which you can choose to be false. Old snippets don't have that flag set and so don't show the output (probably best since the output might have obstructed whatever the old snippet was trying to show).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've used [Firebug JS](https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js) in a few Stack Snippets, since that is what I became used to on JSFiddle (I have the URL bookmarked). It's not the prettiest solution, because it includes pointless HTML<sup>1</sup> (the `script` element) when you are often just trying to demonstrate simple Javascript.

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log('1 + 2 = ' + sum(1, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

---

<sub>*1: See feature request: [Allow to hide sections of Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272351/allow-to-hide-sections-of-stack-snippets)*</sub>

Comment: +1 nice, I haven't thought of this... is the best answer so far (from my point of view), but it still seems a bit too complicated (+ you're relying on a 3rd party script)

Comment: Not too complicated if SO implements FBLite in the snippets :)

Comment: I only see a dialog telling me "Firebug Error: Firebug GUI could not be created."

Comment: @wumm what browser?

Comment: @Sam Safari 7.1 (In Chrome it works for me too)

Comment: Seriously over engineered for a code sample on SO surely.

Comment: Why is it that the non-debug version (https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js) does not work?

Comment: I get "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header." in Chrome when running this snippet.

Comment: Looks like the issue I was experiencing yesterday was because of the ridiculous filter at work - my home computer is fine.

Comment: @TomášZato [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491/260467) really deserves more upvotes, too.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS Chrome.

Answer (score 31):

I quite agree. I made a feature request on MSE to that effect as well: [Add a console to Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/259693)

I also provided a userscript to enable a console. Please download and provide feedback (and up votes ;)),

Comment: Added an extra pane to show the console, that I agree with. Replacing the result pane, not so much.

Answer (score 12):

I gave your question +1, and would hate to see my answer *accepted*, but for what it's worth, there's a simple workaround for basic cases. Add this to your snippet at the top:

```
console.log = function(x) { document.write(x + "<br />"); };
```

Yuck! And also yum!

Example usage:

```js
console.log = function(x) { document.write(x + "<br />"); };

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log('1 + 2 = ' + sum(1, 2));
```

Or you could just use plainly `document.write(1 + 2 = ' + sum(1,2) + '<br \>');` of course ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the input and I promise you that I'll never accept your answer! :)  I would hate to see stackoverflow examples guiding newcomers in the wrong direction. `document.write` is a big **no no** for me.

Comment: Agreed, but hey: it beats `alert` IMHO :D

Comment: :)) right.. at least it places the result in the result panel

Comment: document.write() ... T_T

Comment: Placing the `console.log` in the Result Pane is wrong unless you explain to the OP what you are doing. If you want to show simple output in the DOM what is wrong with `document.write`?

Comment: @Lankymart Hehe, yeah, of course. I thought that was implicit in my answer, guess that could've been missed. Added it as a footnote to the answer.

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me? This seems like one of the few correct uses for `document.write()`? The only problem is that the behaviour of `document.write` is quite different to `console.log`. Try `document.write([])` for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow now supports displaying the results of `console.log` in a code snippet!

Look!

```js
console.log("hello");
console.log("world!");
console.log({foo: "bar"});
```

Comment: Thanks. But good to point adding **`console:true`** to snippet's header: `<!-- begin snippet:js console:true -->`.

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili Tick the "Show console" checkbox in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be best if you could have a separate console output pane under the HTML output pane, and even hide the HTML output pane if it isn't used. In the meantime, this is the workaround I use:

```js
console.log = function(str) {document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + str + '</p>';};

console.log("hello");
console.log("world");
```

Answer (score -4):

> "Should I just open my console in order to see all the complete stack snippet outputs or is there a need of some kind of console API for the stack snippets too?"

`console.log` has many useful scenarios. It is a way to verify what is actually shown if you need verification.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
console.log(a+b);//2
```

The above snippet does not need a special console API. Not only is it obvious that 1+1 is going to be 2 in the console, but a simple `//2` conveys what the user is going to see in the console.

Requiring an answerer to write a whole UI experience showing how to add two numbers would be a massive waste of time for users who already could use more time to spare :)

In more advanced issues, it makes *even more sense* to use the built in behavior of `console.log`.

```js
var complexObject = {};
(function a(i,o){
  if( i == 5 ) return;
  o["a"+i] = {
   val : i
  }
  a(i+1,o["a"+i]);
})(0,complexObject);
console.log(complexObject);//now what?
```

I do not believe an API would help in this scenario. It would have to entirely mock the console to be useful, in which case, given the context the user should probably be expected to at least know what the console is and how to access it. Otherwise, perhaps the user can simply recognize the pattern the recursion is creating as is already the case in every language other than JavaScript on Stack Overflow.

tldr; The team has better things to do with their time than re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score -9):

I believe JS Bin provides the most mature, stable, and well tested way of doing this.

http://jsbin.com/kigegi/1/edit?html,js,console

It's a [Remy Sharp](https://remysharp.com/) project, with 92 other contributors, and it's open-sourced:

https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/MIT-LICENSE.TXT

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: Yes, because it clearly shows console.log() outputting strings, numbers, arrays, objects and html elements to a pane, in a way  familiar way to those who use console.

Comment: It can clearly show what it likes but how does that answer the OPs question? At best it's a comment pointing to an example of an implementation.

Answer (score -11):

I really don't see a need for this.

If the poster has written a Stack-Snippet which shows the results in the console, it is the responsibility of the poster to tell in the post itself that some/all of the results are written to console and how to open it, if it is apparent that the asker is new to web development.

The poster can of course make it easier to see it by including Firebug in the snippet itself like [Sam showed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273125).

The other problem with this *feature-request* is that it doesn't specify what should be logged. Do we really want a separate tool that potentially does the same as the already existing tool? Maybe it is only limited to `console.log`s, but what about `info`, `warn` and `debug`?

The developer tools in the browser can be moved around as a separate window if need be. I don't want to be stuck with a console that I can change when I need to.

**TL;DR:** There is already a perfectly capable tool for that and it should be used.

Comment: If we go by that judgment, why use stack snippets? Aren't there many other good similar tools already out there? What about jsfiddle, codepen, plunkr and many others? The idea behind stack snippets (in my vision at least) is to make it easier for the user to read and write the answer. I'm not saying stack snippets isn't good.. it cool, but there's room for improvement. I would personally want to have a way (without any 3rd party code) to show some simple logs in the **result panel**, even if my result isn't in the form of html/css.

Comment: To my understanding stack-snippets were introduced to keep users on the site and not let them wander off to jsfiddle and the like. Right now Stack-Snippets is tailored to be similar to jsfiddle which also doesn't have an in-page console. The snippets solve the problem for HTML+CSS+JS. A JS-only mode is a different use case. I think it should have a dedicated console, but only when SE introduces other snippets languages.

Comment: @ArtjomB. So basically we shouldn't add a console because others don't have it either?

Comment: @Theolodis I'm saying that it doesn't make sense right now. There is a perfectly versatile solution available. jsFiddle doesn't have it, because they don't need it. But I'm also saying that if we get other language runtimes into the browser, we might need one. But that would depend on the implementation.

Comment: Why so many down-votes? Console is the console a stack snippet is a stack snippet. If your going to write snippets using `console.log` and your OP is new to web development explain where `console.log` can be found. The result pane is the `document` not the console if you want to write out to the `document` then `document.write` is perfectly acceptable (regardless of the naysayers). Don't make the result pane something it isn't! +1

Comment: @canon If your going to write javascript only and use `console.log` don't use a stack snippet it's that simple. What makes me laugh is you talk about *"in a standardized way"* but by making the result pane something it's not your actually breaking the standardized approach it already has.

Comment: @canon That is not what I'm saying at all. Stack Snippets should be used for demoing JavaScript but if they use `console.log` expect the result to be in the developer tools console in the browser. Whereas if you use `document.write` expect the result to be in the results pane of the snippet. This is how the web works, anything else is misguided hacks.

Comment: @canon I can see you're point when you phrase it like that.

Comment: @Canon Still technically  you are still *hacking up* the DOM with your approach. What makes `document.write()` any worse?