# Alert in code snippet a good option

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I have seen many editing the answer, when an alert is found in the code snippet. It will be replaced with `console.log`.

My view is users will be able to see the result instantly rather than opening the developer tools and clicking on console tab to see the result.

So my question is, is `console.log` better than alert?

Comment: IMHO runnable code snippets are bad and mostly misleading, but that's a completely different story.

Comment: This was discussed a while back. It's a matter of opinion so edits like these should be rejected or rolled back.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273049/stack-snippets-console-output