# Stack Snippets and document.write

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718971/476) a user has posted an executable code snippet, which uses `document.write` to show its effect:

```js
var res = ['rwt-cable1', 'rwt-cable42', 'rwt-cable40'].map(e => e.split('-')[1]);

document.write(res);
```

This prompted comments **and downvotes** from several users, admonishing the poster for using `document.write` and giving bad examples. If Javascript isn't your forte: `document.write` is a terrible practice in production code; however, it's also the <del>only</del> shortest way to show the result of otherwise "invisible" code in a code snippet.

What's the community's stance on that? Should bad coding practices be avoided at all cost, **even if it's clearly only for the purpose of demoing it on Stack Overflow?** How should code snippets be used if not this way? Could code snippets be made to output `console.log` calls, which would solve this very elegantly?

Comment: As proven by a moderator, `document.write` is not the only way. He used `document.body.textContent` as a very reasonable replacement.

Comment: somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273049/stack-snippets-console-output would be nice to just be able to have a 'show console' button (opening my own console is too hard)

Comment: @ndugger I'd argue that's not particularly better. You probably wouldn't use either in production code.

Comment: It's better, because it has no pitfalls, and depending on your goal, you absolutely do set the textContent of elements on production code occasionally.

Comment: I would add a notice(comment) right near `document.write` : "Just for test purpose, not production code". If it's just a demo rendering(including suggested notice text), why not?

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort that could be easier spent using a good debugging practice.

Comment: yes, I think that some warning(notice) about some dangerous aspects would be a compromise. Though, it(notice) should be obligatory in such cases

Comment: Requiring disclaimers for every potentially harmful snippet completely removes the point of using short alternatives `document.write`. As long as the ___proper___ method doesn't work (`console.log`), an alternative will have to suffice.

Comment: console.log does work. Just open the console.

Comment: @ndugger That doesn't work in the sense that the output is invisible, unless you know the magic incantation to make it appear. At the very least this too would require a disclaimer/explanation, and a browser-specific one at that. Not terrifically practical either, and much less convenient. And browsers without console (e.g. mobile) are left in the cold entirely.

Comment: It's not magic. Anyone that knows or is learning JS should be aware of the js console. Saying that it's too hard to open it is just laziness.

Comment: @ndugger Again: the issue with using `document.write` is that it "teaches newbies bad practices". But newbies are also the ones who *don't know about the console*. Hiding output in the console doesn't teach newbies anything and just makes them think Stack Snippets are broken or something. At the very least, a lengthy "disclaimer"/tutorial on the console would be needed. And further, again, some browsers don't even have the option of opening a console, making the snippet appear even more broken. It's simply not practical whichever way I turn it.

Comment: One aspect of SO that has been getting lost is that it is *collaboratively edited*.  I blame the edit review queue.  If you see a "bad practice" in code that can be easily corrected then, come on, change it instead of bitching about it.  The edit feature was not just meant to add back-ticks.

Comment: @HansPassant the problem with that is with users like me that have less than 2k rep, and so my edits have to be approved. Usually, OP's will reject my changes if they disagree with good practices, and so then I end up with a bunch of rejected edits.

Comment: In lieu of a disclaimer, could wrap `document.write` in a procedure called `neverDoThisEverThisIsJustToShowStuffHereOnStackOverflowButDontUseElsewhereOrKittensWillGetHurt`.

Comment: @HansPassant we still don't have an acceptable, standard way to show console output in the snippet result pane. I don't know that I'd call it bitching to look for some direction... there are bad choices everywhere. The only decent option is to have SO integrate some mirrored console visualization, i.e.: output console messages to both the console and the DOM.

Comment: Also, you can't use `document.write` in XHTML. You simply get an error if you try. One more reason why I love XHTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now possible to use a virtual console in stack snippets:

[Source Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console)

Example:

```js
console.log('console!!')
console.log([1,2,3])
console.log({i: 'think', this: 'is', cool: '!'})
console.log(console.log)
throw new Error('test')
```

Comment: :thumbsup: :+1: #finally Yay!

Answer (score 32):

> even if it's clearly only for the purpose of demoing it on Stack Overflow?

My problem with willy-nilly tossing `document.write` into answers **without disclaimer** is that *many* new JavaScript developers will be reading the answer and taking the entire thing in, not instinctively knowing that `document.write` was used for *this platform's* demonstration purposes.  This can lead to a lot of headaches and bugs for the early developer that could be avoided (IMO) with one line of text (or not proliferating document.write).

With that said, I think we should put a little more pressure on getting some sort of console output to the stack snippets, or informing people to open their consoles and use the debugging tools they already have. I know this is a pipe-dream to some, but hey, I'm a dreamer.

Comment: You might say you're a dreamer, but you're not the only one.

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36484253/774078)

Comment: @Sterling That might equally prompt questions from newbies what that external include is for and whether that's needed to make the answer work...

Comment: @deceze are you against new coders learning/teaching them things or something? If they ask, point them in the right direction. It's super easy

Comment: @rlemon While I agree in principle with your idealism, I don't think it's very practical. Any solution will prompt newbies to become confused. Tell them to open their console... *what's a console?* Use external includes to make `console.log` work... *do I need that in my code?* Use `document.write`... *do I need that in my code?*

Comment: @Sterling So what about teaching them that `document.write` is for demonstration purposes only?

Comment: Teach smarter, not harder

Comment: @deceze Ideally, Stack snippets would just show the console along with the actual output.

Comment: `/* For demonstration purposes only */ document.write(myFunction)` How 'bout that?

Comment: @Madara I'm all for *that* ideal, yes. :)

Comment: @rlemon Since you're emphasising "**without disclaimer**", you're fine with `document.write` as long as it's accompanied by a disclaimer?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, as pointed out, the disclaimer is kinda lame and we shouldn't need to add it, the tool should offer debugging output. I would love it if this sparked some more focus on touching up the stack snippets. (I'm really trying to push that if you can't tell :D)

Comment: I think we're all on the same side there. Could we agree not to punish posters trying to work around this limitation then? If you spot someone `document.write`ing, how about simply editing their answer to add the "necessary" disclaimer?

Comment: @deceze [that script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491/159427) is supposed to be accompanied by an HTML comment `<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->` but most people tend to omit it. I've resisted editing answers to include that comment... but I'm very tempted. That said, if you remove my script, nothing breaks. You still have your `console.log()` statements and they keep on doing whatever they were doing before.

Comment: Couldn't `console.log` or another `console` method be overwritten to write to the document before code snippet is run and restored after. Maybe Stack Overflow would do it when clicked on the run code snippet button. Another option is to allow us to write hidden code so we can modify `console.log`. A workaround would be to add the modifying code as external source.

Comment: Let's just use good ol' `alert`, it's obvious that one is only for demonstration purposes :-)

Answer (score 25):

In my ***opinion***, `document.write` is fine, ***provided*** it's only used to output some variables in a snippet.

I'm not saying `document.write` itself is fine. **`document.write` *as* an answer is (nearly) always *bad*.**

If a line of code is used just to output the result of code that's actually relevant to the question, then that code really isn't part of the answer.
We can't expect everyone to add disclaimers to every single snippet of potentially sub-optimal code, when said code is used to illustrate an example.

Disclaimers completely remove the point of a quick short function call that outputs the answer, since those disclaimers often are longer than the "proper" way to return a result.

---

As long as SO doesn't add some kind of `console.log` support for snippets, just use `document.write`.

In the end, it's *your* answer.
If you feel like adding a disclaimer with `document.write`, no-one will stop you.
If you feel like using a different method, go for it.

In the end, there's no pleasing everyone. Some users will downvote for `document.write`, other users will downvote because the snippet isn't working if you use `console.log` (Since they didn't bother looking at the console). Other users will downvote for the use of a small library to output the result.

Comment: Agreed. IMO it's no different from a lot of `echo $result` we see for all sorts of languages, simply because for the purposes of demonstration, you want *some output*. That it's not going to be used that way *in production* is or should be implicitly understood.

Comment: sounds a lot like the w3schools mentality "well that isn't related, so ignore how bad it is"

Comment: @rlemon: I'm disappointed you drawn a comparison with w3fools. I'm not going to respond to straw man replies like that.

Comment: but you just did? in any case I stand by my comparison. bad code is bad code. showing it in an answer, however brief, *is* going to make someone believe it is acceptable. Please avoid this.

Comment: @deceze: Exactly my point. If snippets supported `console.log`, we'd all use that. Since that's not available and `document.write` works perfectly fine ___for snippets___, why not?

Comment: @rlemon: I suggest you add a answer to this meta question, explaining that point of view.

Comment: I thought that was fairly transparent at this point. I don't think we should be using document.write in answers because "there is no better alternative". I've linked a related post in the Question and feel correcting stack snippets should be the focus. In lieu of that, document.write is still wrong.

Comment: @rlemon It'd be helpful if you formulated that as answer so people can vote on it and we can gauge the community consensus.

Comment: In the end, the problem is the lack of a safe/proper/easy method to output data from snippets. A `console.log` expansion would go a long way in reducing the use of `document.write`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this should be (zealously?) discouraged. Here's an excerpt from my response to a [plea for integrated console visualization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/159427):

> If the point of these snippets is to enable us to demo functionality and display its output inline, the output pane needs to be adapted to (optionally) mirror logged messages. We certainly don't want `document.write()` in the middle of what should be a node.js function.

And it's not just about polluting the code. `document.write()` introduces other issues and unexpected behavior to the novice user even in the *intended* environment.

This discussion should ultimately lead to a feature-request for a built-in snippet-console. Unfortunately, that request already exists and it has languished, unloved, for 1.5 years.

So, until someone at SO deems it important (and I encourage you to upvote that [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/159427)), I've been using [my own script for console output](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491/159427). While I'd love to drop it in lieu of an integrated feature... alas.

Here's a handy-dandy copy/paste block:

```html
<!-- console visualization; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a small demo:

```js
// sample values
var values = [1e100, "a", true, new Date(), x => 1, /(?:)/ig, undefined, null];

// log whole array
console.log("whole array: %o", values);

// add a circular reference
values.push(values);

// log whole array 
console.log("array with circular reference: %o", values);

// remove circular reference
values.pop();

// log each value individually
values.forEach((v, i) => console.log("%i: %o", i, v));
```

```html
<!-- console visualization; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Once we have an official feature, we can roll through and remove that script wholesale... and everything will work nicely.

<sub>As of this writing, my script turns up in [179 search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2F%2Fgh-canon.github.io%2Fstack-snippet-console%2Fconsole.min.js).</sub>
<sub>T.J. Crowder's [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/159427) shows up in [**660** results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2F%2Ftjcrowder.github.io%2Fsimple-snippets-console%2Fsnippet.js)!</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what's wrong with using any tool at your disposal, as long as you use it responsibly. If it's insidious like `document.write`, `eval()`, or using `<table>` for layout purposes, I would briefly state that it is not a good practice and it's being used for demonstration purposes.

I hated using `console.log` for anything but debugging until I found this script:

```
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

**[GITHUB](https://github.com/gh-canon)**

It displays `console.log`, so now you can share your results on the console without having to inform OP about using devtools. Hell it's so cool, I look for questions that give me an excuse to use `console.js`.

Comment: The problem with including scripts like that is that you will have to include a disclaimer that it's just for demo purposes, just as you'd have to add a disclaimer to `write` and other alternatives.

Comment: That's true, never thought about it that way. I'll add a comment with that particular snippet for now on and backtrack on the ones that don't have a disclaimer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it were otherwise reasonable (I *have* used it in production code before, in rare cases), `document.write()` is semantically incorrect in almost ever case it's used like this, because it outputs raw HTML, and they're trying to output plain text. This is the same kind of mis-thinking (really, it's a non-language enforced type error; it's *incorrect* code) that leads to security vulnerabilities, and we should avoid ever demonstrating code like that.

If the answer is otherwise good, I'd probably only leave a comment. But if the answer is borderline, this would tip the balance and justify a downvote.

Answer (score -2):

Since we're constrained to executing JavaScript in the context of a web page, I would guide users toward standard DOM manipulation techniques.

```js
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "I usually just do this.";
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

```js
var log = (function(output) {
    return function(text) {
      output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text + "<br/>");
    }
  })(document.getElementById("output"));

log("This is for when I'm feeling really fancy.");
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score -11):

Really, why is there a meta question for something ... silly? If you're a front-end developer, you should be familiar with the console. It's a truly golden tool for developing front-end applications.

When someone have `console.log()` in their snippet, it *should* be a reflex to open the console window. It's *nothing more* than pressing one button: F12.

Yes, I have seen the question and the answer. This caused a small controversy in the Javascript chat room. I even said the following

> :/ `document.write`. I wouldn't have an issue if this method got removed from the js engines. [sauce](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30031812#30031812)

We should be aware that there are developers (I call them "google developers") which have a problem with their code, or an issue to translate a problem to solution. They just google it (most of us do that. I even do that). Buuuuuuutttt ... at a large group of these, it even became a habit that they do the following;

1. open google
2. enter the keywords
3. scanning results and sees the SO post with relevant/similar question
4. opens the link, checks the question. If valid go to 5 else go to 3
5. goes to (voted/accepted) answer
6. copy answer then paste it in their code.

See, no attempt to **comprehend** the code! Just click, select, `Ctrl`+`C`, click, `Ctrl`+`V`.

In this situation, they would copy over

```
var res = ['rwt-cable1', 'rwt-cable42', 'rwt-cable40'].map(e => e.split('-')[1]);
document.write(res);
```

And then modify the variables / array / whateverIdunwannaknow...

Who knows if they would use the above in production? The snippet absolutely does not say something about the caveats that `document.write` causes.

In this context, I truly understand that it's not easy to show the results in the code snippet but really, there are other alternatives like `document.body.textContent`. It's ugly too, but far better than `document.write`. Using alerts is a form of bad example too, but I have seen starter Javascript developers that uses it to debug their code. Who knows from where they got their debugging strategy?

Demonizing the user whom has posted the above function isn't what I would do (I even don't downvote posts if it's *so* bad. I advise them some improvements when possible), but for the sake of future users: **write best of practice codes in your answer**.

That would avoid future issues with new developers. I'm in QA branch and I see codes from users that clearly doesn't know what they did ON WEEKLY BASE... So there are plenty of those "google developers"...

But but... what about disclaimers? " Should I not add it? ". Well the word says it already: *disclaimer*. You don't have to be a language professor to know what that does with the reader.

Comment: IMO we can't possibly be responsible for shoddy developers. If you are the sort of developer that copy and pastes Google code without the least bit of comprehension or clean up, **then anything you produce will suck by definition** and no amount of discipline by SO posters will change that. At least `document.write` has very visible output or breakage; if you're *still* leaving it in your code regardless, we cannot help you.

Comment: *At least document.write has very visible output or breakage* You need to know that it is not true. In a small example it's fine. It doesn't lead to code breaks. So the first user will think that it's OK. And *we can't possibly be responsible for shoddy developers* = stepping away of your responsibilities.

Comment: No, we *are not* responsible for what other developers produce. We can provide examples at best, we never provide production code. We *cannot* provide production code. All code on the site here must always be adjusted for the particular situation it's going to be used in. We can't possibly provide code which will always do the right thing in every situation as is. **Especially if that involves any sort of _demo_ output.**

Comment: We are responsible for pointing out *more or less subtle shortcomings*, along the lines of *"this obviously needs data validation and error handling"* or *"note that this will fail in ways X or Y if Z."* Pointing out that the output this code produces is probably not something you're going to use in production is overboard IMO. That should be obvious to anyone who's reading the code. If you're not reading the code, we cannot help you.