# When was "include console" option added to the Snippets

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

When did the "include console" option get added?

[image]

```js
console.log("Test");
```

Had still been using my own methods to display logs when just today I seen the option in the snippet editor. Did I miss something letting us know it was there, is it part of a beta feature, or is it relatively new?

Comment: The mods apparently haven't gotten around to marking [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273049) as [status-complete]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was announced [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279420/stack-snippets-upgrade-virtual-console) and according to that post its implementaton was pretty recent i.e. around about the 18th May 2016.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, guess I will have to look at the other meta site more often