# Code Snippet Summary

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

I stumbled across this question: [Vertical align span text inside inline-block div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457954/vertical-align-span-text-inside-inline-block-div) and noted that the question itself could be improved to use code snippets -- as you can see I have done.

However, thinking for feng-shui purposes that the accepted answer (which links to js-fiddle) would also benefit, I realised a problem. The answer had provided example code which highlighted the salient points of the answer, without providing the complete code (which I found to be a fab' way to answer).

So, if I were to edit the answer to use code snippets, the answer would get ugly, with lots of irrelevant bits of code.

It would be nice to be able to have a 5th (!!) area in the edit code snippet such that you can specify a 'summary' of the code. Alternatively, a checkbox on css/html/js to 'hide' that part of the snippet from the answer.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

*Runnable code snippets are often called Stack Snippets, which is what I refer to them as.*

I agree that it would useful to have a way to hide code in Stack Snippets, **but I see this opening the door to abuse**. You are hiding parts of the code from future readers, which could be really unexpected if someone was looking at the code and expecting everything.

To quote a better answer from [Allow to hide sections of Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272351/359284) by [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9):

> At best, such behavior would break the assumption that snippets are self-contained solutions - if you think you're seeing everything needed to accomplish a task while in fact key elements are hidden, confusion will result.

---

Stack Snippets were introduced as a common feature request for **runnable code snippets**. You can find the introduction post at [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

The key part there is that **they should be used for runnable code snippets**. This makes them incredibly useful for demonstrating full HTML/JavaScript questions and answers, giving you the ability to demonstrate the problem and solution. They are meant to replace plain code blocks in those cases, and **should not be used unless the snippets are runnable**.

There is no use in demonstrating only parts of a code, when you need the full code for it to run.

Comment: I completely agree, except for the notion that you need the complete code. Doesn't `printf("hello world");` reveal enough information without needing to also supply `int main() { ... }`? If you look at the two answers given in the post I linked to, both give just enough code to highlight where the solution lies. Both _also_ link to a fully working demonstration. In my mind, this is the best of both worlds: short and succinct answers, but with complete working demo code. I don't see either of the answers given in my example post to be confusing in the slightest.