# Sandbox the console separately?

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Consider the below Snippet:

```js
console.log("Hello.");
console.log("OMG. See how big?");
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed #f90;
  background: #fc6;
  line-height: 5;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Because of the CSS I used, the console is messed up. Can this be sandboxed or fixed?

In contrast, here's what the console is supposed to look like:

```js
console.log("Hello.");
console.log("How it's supposed to look.");
```

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid CSS on *all* `div`s anyway? I mean, this is kind of exactly why you would want to follow that as a best practice, I think...

Comment: @jpmc26 no, in my opinion if you want to make an answer here on SO you may want to keep your snippet as simple as possible why complicate with another container or extra classes that doesn't add any value to the real code issue just to avoid the bug of the snippets ...

Comment: @DaniP Because of novices who won't recognize that you're using bad practices and will make someone else's life a living hell trying to clean up their uninformed mess. Why does it have to be complicated, anyway? Just add a stinkin' ID or class. It's not that complex.

Comment: @jpmc26 I guess that is another discussion and isn't the topic of the question itself each scenario has its own particularities, there is no bad practice here.

Comment: @DaniP It's absolutely relevant. SO shouldn't spend a lot of time implementing features that shouldn't be necessary in a good post.

Comment: Console has more issues than just being slightly overlapping with the div styling. It was a hacky solution, and so that is what you are using. If you ask me, there shouldn't even need to be a built in "console". If a user does not know what a console is, then it is more important to teach them how to use the console than anything else in their more than likely low quality question.

Comment: @TravisJ Agreed half-heartedly with you.

Comment: Flawed very much!

Comment: My only concern with this is that is may invalidate posts that rely on this bug. They are probably very infrequent (if in existence at all) so I say go for it.

Comment: @jpmc26 What you should do isn't what you get on Stack Overflow. It's it's  not a valid argument to blame the user.

Comment: Agreed whole heartedly with @MadaraUchiha! `:)`

Comment: @jpmc26 When people are able to write professional code, why do they come to Stack Overflow? They want their **** code to be corrected. So when the **** code is put inside the snippet, then it breaks the snippet, which shouldn't happen. This is what my argument is.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: _"They want their bad code to be corrected."_ That's not what SO is for. We're not a code reviewing service.

Comment: @Cerbrus Most of them come here with bad code - Agree or not?

Comment: Most come here with _broken_ code. SO's focus is on helping solve _programming issues_, to become a repository of _quality_ Q/A. We don't have to put up with junk questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus Agreed, but at the same time, that bad code should not break the existing site right? `:(`

Comment: @TravisJ I disagree, displaying the snippet's console output on the page itself is an extremely useful UX improvement which is helpful to all users, regardless of whether or not they know how to use their browser's built-in console. I shouldn't need to open the devtools in my browser in order to use Stack Overflow. I agree though that the current implementation is really hacky and should be fixed.

Comment: @Ajedi32 - You shouldn't need to use any sort of tooling to use Stack Overflow? Are you writing code on napkins? :) Most users here validate code with an IDE, and simply showing a console.log result in a JavaScript relevant post which actually enables the "use of Stack Overflow" for users is very narrow.

Comment: @TravisJ No, you shouldn't need any development tooling to use basic features of the Stack Overflow website itself. The whole point of runnable snippets (vs just code blocks) is to get the added convenience of _not_ needing to copy code into a development tool in order to see what it does. Being able to see the result of scripts which use console.log as their output is an important part of that.

Comment: Meh, kind of a LCD outlook. Stack Overflow got along just fine for years and millions of posts without snippets or logging to a fake console. If anything, the argument could be made that not allowing users to discover the actual developer tooling is hampering their development. Also, there are probably very many SO users who can determine code output by inspection alone, even on a napkin.

Answer (score 19):

Don't change this.

I regularly see users leverage this to change the console output:

```js
console.log("Gee,\n\nthis\n\nis\n\na\n\nlo\no\no\no\no\no\no\nng\n\nstring!");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is very convenient if the only output you have is some `console.log` statements. Changing this will also break those existing answers.

If you *have* to have a CSS rule on all `div` tags, just add a wrapper in your answer:

```js
console.log("Yay, the console isn't red!");
```

```css
.wrapper div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I'd even argue that this has educational value, as it's a perfect example of why CSS classes on all `div` elements are troublesome.

Comment: Telling you again, when noobs come with yucky code, they might mess up the console right? I really agree with the "leverage" part. `:)`

Comment: We can't expect stack snippets to work, regardless of what "noobs" throw at them. At some point, we have to say: _"If it's not working, fix your snippet's code"_

Comment: This workaround would be obviated by making the console area vertically resizable. :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure we can. Wrap the console in an ID, use a proper reset with high specificity. Then you can still override stuff if you *really* want to, but accidental alterations are unlikely.

Comment: There could be a `console.maximize()` method, or something like that. [The console should be isolated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279561/195099)

Comment: I don't really see any use case for this that wouldn't be better addressed by a change to the global styling of the console across all answers. For instance, if being able to view long strings like that is an issue, then the console UI should be made resizable. Furthermore, you shouldn't be including code in your snippets that isn't relevant to the answer you're posting. It's just noise.

Comment: @Ajedi32, it's not just noise.  Often "superfluous" CSS makes the answer clearer (outlining, highlighting, readability, etc.) While test buttons are useful to test/show dynamic parts of the code but aren't part of the answer themselves. ... It would be nice to be able to hide/minimize this "presentation" code separately though.

Comment: @BrockAdams I think there's a difference between "this code helps illustrate the answer", and "this code makes the snippet's console look pretty". One is code the reader might actually be interested in reading in order to better understand the answer, while the other is completely irrelevant noise. (Or worse, actively confusing to readers who don't understand what it's intended to do.) But yes, I do agree that in some situations it might be helpful to be able to collapse sections of snippets. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272351/1157054

Comment: Wouldn't a `.as-console-wrapper,.as-console-wrapper *{all:unset}` rule be better though? Would still not fix the js side of the problem, but at least, we would still be able to style the console on purpose, and in the mean wouldn't do it accidentally by any selector with lower priority than `.as-console-wrapper`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this should be fixed. CSS leaking into the console isn't the only issue; there are a lot of potential problems that can be caused by the fact that the console isn't isolated from the rest of the snippet.

For example, here is an additional test case taken from [Oriol's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279561/192171) to the original post on SE meta announcing the introduction of the console feature (modified slightly to better illustrate the problem):

```js
// Demonstration that `length` on the jQuery instance will be 0
// if there are no matching elements. There are no `div` elements
// in this snippet.
$(function() {
  console.log("Number of div elements:", $("div").length);
});
```

```html
<p>No div elements here!</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Yes, you can work around these issues as the snippet author once you realize what the problem is, but you really shouldn't have to; the console should not be able to interfere with the behavior of snippets.

---

To address some of the points made in a few of the other answers to this question:

**But isn't using a generic selector like `div` in your snippet a bad idea anyway?**

No, using simplified code like the example above is a perfectly acceptable way to illustrate a concept like the behavior of a method or CSS property.

Yes, using it in production where you have other divs on the page you don't want to count would be incorrect, but "counting divs" isn't the point of the answer; illustrating the usage of the length property is. There are numerous other situations where simplified examples like this are appropriate.

**But I like being able to style the console to make it work better/look nicer in my snippets!**

Using code in your snippet to modify the behavior of the console is a neat hack, but it's still just that: a hack. It'd be far better for Stack Overflow to incorporate those improvements into the console itself so that all answers can benefit from them. (For example, rather than you using CSS to increase the display size of the console, Stack Overflow should just make the console resizable.)

Additionally, including code like that in your answers which has no relevance to the question whatsoever is noise at best, and at worst can be confusing to readers who don't understand what that extra code is meant to be doing. (E.g. "Why is he styling `.as-console-wrapper`? I don't see that in the snippet code.")

Comment: In situations where console output is required (aka including the console is required), it's overwhelmingly unlikely that CSS is required. So we should really be educating users to write more minimal MCVEs, instead.

Comment: @TylerH Again, CSS isn't the only potential problem here. The example I gave in my answer is a very minimal snippet using JS and the DOM, yet it is still affected by this issue.

Comment: Still, why would you be selecting all the div elements, and not educating the user that they should be using a more specific selector to mitigate such an issue in the first place.

Comment: @TinyGiant Because the details of what selector you're using are not relevant to the problem, or even the focus of the answer. In which case simpler is better.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think this is worth spending time implementing. You shouldn't be globally assigning a style to `div` in professional code, anyway. As I understand it (as a developer not focused on HTML/CSS/JS), this would be very bad form since the `div` element is so generic. Just use a class. It's simple and will actively improve your post.

```js
console.log("Hello.");
console.log("OMG. See how big?");
```

```css
.myclass {
  border: 1px dashed #f90;
  background: #fc6;
  line-height: 5;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: If the downvoters would like to point out any incorrect statements or anything I'm missing, I'd be all too willing to learn.

Comment: Man, this is a flaw with the system okay? I am trying to make sure the system is flawless. Don't you understand the question at all? This is not Stack Overflow for correcting the code. And ps: **downvotes here doesn't cause you any damage**.

Comment: I fail to see how it's a flaw if the page does exactly what you told it to: style all `div`s. P.S. I know what downvotes are for here. I still like to know what causes disagreement with an answer I post.

Comment: No, I didn't ask that the console should follow the styles that are inside the page. `:)`

Comment: It's like this. You are not sanitizing the user's inputs on a login application, and *preaching*, **Users should input only their username and password, not SQL Injection attacks!** The developer is the lame loser! Do you not make it fail-safe?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's a computer. It does what you tell it to. Your code *does* say, "style all `div`s thusly". You can't argue against that. If for some reason, you think it shouldn't do exactly what you told it to, then you need more explanation. And we're talking about page appearance, not data loss here.

Comment: Man, I am not sure if you are trolling me or you genuinely don't understand the issue here.

Comment: I understand the issue. I'm saying, "Don't do things you shouldn't do anyway, and don't ask other people to waste time implementing features to make it easier for you to create lower quality content."

Comment: People Misuse. We have to be ethical hackers. Period.

Comment: totally agree to not spend time on fixing this.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, and creating lower quality content is misusing. =) If this is an actual vulnerability, then please edit your question to show how it can misused and I'll delete my answer. There's no "ethics" here unless this is actually dangerous. Or you could argue that this isn't bad practice, as I've stated it is. If I'm right about it being bad practice, though, you shouldn't post this code anyway even if they do make changes to accommodate. As it stands, your responses have no actual substance.

Comment: @jpmc26 Since this is just a CSS thing, it cannot be misused. Let's say, a noob, who posts a CSS question and asks for help (where the code written is crap) and then it uses global tag styles, then obviously the console gets affected. What if, `div {position: absolute !important;}` is one of the definitions? And the noob is here to genuinely get fixed, but the console is coming up and messing his code?

Comment: @jpmc26 Lemme tell you, there is **no vulnerability** here. I don't mind the lazy people telling don't fix, but seriously, if I was the product owner, I'll make sure this gets fixed ASAP. This is a bug, a confirmed UI loopwhole in the system. Who now-a-days takes UI seriously? That's the reason! `:(` ps: I am a UX Architect, it pricks me.

Comment: If people were able to write professional code *correctly*, they wouldn't be asking questions about it. So this seems like a relatively poor argument for fixing a UX problem on a Q&A site.

Comment: It is not inherently bad form to add styles to the generic `div` tag with `div {}`. Sloppy code that does that is bad because it's sloppy, not because it's bad form. Sometimes it's efficient and semantic to do it.

Comment: 2 delete votes on a perfectly valid answer. Guys, even _if_ the answer is wrong, that's not a reason to delete it.

Comment: So many downvotes? :O