# SO CSS animations overriding snippet CSS animations

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Take the code below, which should flash the `<div>` from red to blue:

```css
@keyframes flash {
    from { background-color: red; }
    to {background-color: blue; }
}

div {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: flash 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>I should be flashing from red to blue!</div>
```

I came across this recently [while answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617124/active-state-of-button-fades-after-clicking/51617348#51617348) and spent about 10 minutes trying to figure out how I had gone so horribly wrong, before realizing that some of SO's CSS was overriding my own.

Is this known? Are there other examples of this?

Comment: The default styles should be inserted before the user-entered styles. Currently it's the other way around. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPWqU.png

Comment: ***S t a c k S n i p p e t s a r e t h e s u p e r i o r H T M L / C S S / J S r u n n a b l e s n i p p e t s o l u t i o n***

Comment: (This is an issue with pretty much *all* sites of this kind - it's only egregious on Stack Snippets because 1) it was introduced as an in-house alternative to third-party off-site solutions and 2) apparently Stack Snippets even threw in a gratuitous animation.)

Comment: All that CSS for the console, which [was a user contribution.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491/288751) There is a feature request to [Sandbox the console separately](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339480/4639281).

Comment: Woow, they really used an animation called *flash*, am pretty sure it's new, right?

Comment: That looks like flashing yellow to blue here. Is it supposed to do that?

Comment: @Mast which browser? you shouldn't see the blue at all ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif A very faintish white-blue. Firefox Quantum 61.0.1 x64

Comment: I might be wrong about the blue, seeing colours is a subjective thing after all and the suggestion of there being something blue on your screen does wonders, but [this is definitely yellow, not red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/959wZ.png).

Comment: It seems to be fading from yellow to white to me, @Mast. Precisely the animation you see when following a link to an answer or comment; it will *flash* (ha!) for a moment to highlight it.

Comment: I wonder how shadow dom would fix this?

Comment: @BoltClock It's better broken than not-working at all after one year :)

Comment: Serves you right for using such a: generic, overloaded, common, almost-meaningless, label as "flash". ;)  You should use something helpful and uniquely descriptive like "redToBlue", or "flashRedBlu", or "copFlash", etc.

Comment: I ran into this the other day and wasted time in much the same way.  I feel bad I didn't make post about it now but I thought it was known.

Comment: @Braiam Not consistently at all, tbh. Browsers need to hurry up with support for that.

Answer (score 15):

It's the snippet console CSS, evidenced by disabling the console output:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->
```

Demo:

```css
@keyframes flash {
    from { background-color: red; }
    to {background-color: blue; }
}

div {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    animation: flash 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div>I should be flashing from red to blue!</div>
```

A quick fix would be for SO to rename `flash` to `as-console-flash` (or whatever namespaced variant they choose).

Still, the whole thing ought to be redone to sandbox the console visualization via shadow dom (lol?), frame messaging, or something.

Comment: It's also definitely `stacksnippets.net`, because the two look identical when the JavaScript for the site is disabled.

Comment: So, I'm somewhat inexperienced with Meta - for a bug report, what criteria must an answer meet for me to mark it accepted? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @TylerRoper Hopefully a StackExhange employee will post an answer stating they've fixed the issue and you can accept that.