# Add an option to hide or collapse less relevant snippet sections

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Snippets are very useful, but often fill up a lot of the answer with irrelevant code.

(E.g. in JavaScript questions, often the solution can be demonstrated by changing a tiny part of the JavaScript code. It's annoying to have to scroll through line-after-line of HTML and CSS before you can click "Run Snippet").

It would be nice if the snippet had options to show the languages of your choosing.

E.g. at the moment

```
<!--begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    i = 1;
    $('.pointer').click(function(){
      elem = $(this).children("img")[0];

      $({rotation: 225*!i}).animate({rotation: 225*i}, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now) {
          $(elem).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'});
        }
      });
      i=!i;
    });

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .container{
      width:100%;
      padding-top:100px;
      padding-bottom:100px;
      background-color:#000;
      text-align:center;
      font-size:20px;
      color:#fff;
    }

    .coolImage{
      height:17px;
      width:17px;
      margin-left:7px;
    }

    .pointer{
      cursor:pointer;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="pointer">
    CLICK ME<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgf0C.png" class="coolImage">
    </div>

    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Shows in the answer as:

[image]

But imagine if we could add e.g. `hide: true` to each language separately:

```
<!--begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    i = 1;
    $('.pointer').click(function(){
      elem = $(this).children("img")[0];

      $({rotation: 225*!i}).animate({rotation: 225*i}, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now) {
          $(elem).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ now +'deg)'});
        }
      });
      i=!i;
    });

<!-- language: lang-css hide: true -->

    .container{
      width:100%;
      padding-top:100px;
      padding-bottom:100px;
      background-color:#000;
      text-align:center;
      font-size:20px;
      color:#fff;
    }

    .coolImage{
      height:17px;
      width:17px;
      margin-left:7px;
    }

    .pointer{
      cursor:pointer;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html hide: true -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="pointer">
    CLICK ME<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgf0C.png" class="coolImage">
    </div>

    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

[image]

Now it shows only the relevant code, so it is much cleaner.

Comment: Another use case for this is to hide the CSS tweak `.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }`. Alternatively, this tweak could be built-in into the snippet tool.

Comment: One concern is that it's not immediately clear quite a lot of snippet things are hidden here which may lead people thinking 1) you've not provided an MCVE leading to close votes/comments asking you to include your html/css etc... 2) you're attempting to do something nefarious by hiding certain portions of the code.

Comment: @JonClements what do you think of the edit

Comment: Might as well make that a "v Hide JS" jobby as well so it's a consistent UI I guess... then people can expand/collapse as necessary...

Comment: For the case you make in your question, just post the relevant parts of the code modifications in their own code block and hide the whole runnable snippet. For the case Xufox made (where we need to use bloated workarounds to come to a should be normal behavior), that's more an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: @JonClements I think this is a good idea really. If the answer changes only, e.g. the HTML, it might be useful to hide the CSS and JS and only show the HTML block and "Run" button. Currently, hiding the entire snippet has the effect that running it is a two-step process; click "Show" first and then "Run". That could be improved.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272351/allow-to-hide-sections-of-stack-snippets?rq=1

Comment: @JonClements Experienced users would definitely know of this feature. About 2, I don't know but I don't think JS in the snippet can do anything harmful (XSS?)