# Is there a way to only show the console in Stack Snippets?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I was asking a question on Stack Overflow, and I needed to insert a Stack Snippet. The snippet only logged one thing to the console. The console only took a little bit of the screen; the rest of the screen was left unused.

I was wondering, is there any way to make the Stack Snippet console-only?

Comment: Related: [Add an option to hide or collapse less relevant snippet sections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376217/4642212).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The console within Stack Snippets is rendered inside the output, so it can be manipulated using CSS.

A one-liner like this hides the normal output and shows nothing but the console:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
console.log("Only the console is shown here.");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from("Hello, world!"), null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

Comparison without `.as-console-wrapper`:

```js
console.log("Only the console is shown here.");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from("Hello, world!"), null, 2));
```