# Can I ask a question about a library that does not have a tag?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to ask a question on Stack Overflow about an open source library that does not have a tag. The library is mostly commented in Chinese, but its variables, methods, and class names are all in English. I don't know if the question is not for Stack Overflow because there is not a tag? Or because it is not commented in English? I do not want to get downvoted for asking a question that does not belong.

The library is FineUI and it is ExtJS based.

Comment: If your question is otherwise on topic as defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then you can ask your question. Pick other tags to categorize the question appropriately. From there, you can either link back here in the hopes a 1.5k rep or higher user adds the tag to the question for you, or you can leave a comment on the question requesting the addition of a tag.

Comment: Also, see the FAQ: [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: You'll be almost certainly wasting your time at SO.  You're much better off contacting the company for support or looking for a Chinese web site.

Comment: @HansPassant Why do you think that?

Comment: @Phillip If you ask the question and drop a link on meta (or even when you don't) you have a high chance that some high-rep user with tag creation privilege will edit your question to contain the tag, thus creating it. Your question is on-topic here. Have a nice stay.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It isn't a requirement for posts to have the exact tag. It is even the other way around, there first need to be a post before it can get a tag.

If a tag does exist or not is not a qualifier or disqualifier for questions being on-topic. From the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Questions about the use of a function from a library in context with ExtJS is a specific programming problem that is a practical answerable problem and therefor on topic.

You do have a special problem because the library is commented in Chinese and some might find it difficult to dive in and help out.

To overcome that special case make sure your question is above average in the quality range, apply all guidance from [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so users can try, [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) and debug your issue on their own, share your assumptions, what you already did find out, maybe you manage to google translate some bits.

If you recognize that you have a special case and show and share the extra effort you made to help others provide you with an answer I would be surprised if your question gets down voted or even closed.

We have users from China so I expect they will grab their chance to work with you to find an answer.