# Do I still need to provide code sample even if I am providing fiddle link?

Tags: discussion, support

One of my previously posted question is put on hold, being tagged as off-topic.

I have some confusions regarding this.

Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654709/hide-an-option-form-the-list-when-its-selected-and-vice-cersa-using-chosen-plugi

Why is the question being stated off-topic?

I have provided a fiddle link, and explained it clearly.

Is there something I am missing out?

Is it because I have not provided any sample code? But as you can see, I have provided the fiddle link.

Is fiddle link not considered as a code explanation?

Comment: But there are many questions on SO, which don't have code samples. Is it mandatory to put code sample? Or I do need to provide code sample, every time I will be providing a fiddle? @FrédéricHamidi. And lastly, why is put as off-topic then? Its surely a jquery related question

Comment: @Saswat And what if that fiddle link dies?  The question becomes useless to future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @Saswat, it is mandatory to provide a code sample when you provide a jsFiddle link (for the reasons explained by Daedalus). As for the close reason, the explanation is readily available in the close banner: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* ***in the question itself.***

Comment: @Daedalus, ah yes. I didn't think like that. Actually, previously when I used to provide some code sample(for complex codes) people used to ask me for fiddle. So I thought that providing only fiddle will do, because lot of people ask for fiddle. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Instead of a fiddle, did you consider using a Stack Snippet instead?

Comment: @Saswat the requests for fiddles generally predated the introduction of native "Stack Snippets", and **never** replaced the need for code in the posts themselves.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, but sir, *the desired behaviour* is explained as *requirement*. And the fiddle itself is *the shortest code* and the *error happening*. Is it tagged offtopic for not providing the code sample directly into the question?

Comment: @Saswat yes, exactly; if you edit it to remove the noise and move the fiddle into a stack snippet, it will get reopened. You can then add an answer to show what actually worked for you (again, with a snippet). In the future, please don't just cheat your way into posting by applying random code formatting.

Comment: @Saswat It also quite clearly says 'in the question itself'; don't discount one line because another exists.

Comment: @rene, Actually I tried once. But couldn't understand how to add codes, or external links. :(

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why that shouldn;t work, did you go over the examples [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)? Might be worth another meta post ;)

Comment: @rene, No I have decided not to post anything on meta from now onwards. It displeases some people and I just invite a series of downvotes. I tried to get some example of how to write in snippets, but due to some reasons, wasn't successful. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: well, on meta voting is different so I wouldn't be to concerned about that. The votes mainly convey that they disagree with you that a jsfiddle is enough. No reputation is hurt in the process...

Comment: I am not worried about meta. After I had discussion over here, I rectified my question and edited it. Still after the edit, I am getting negative points. That's why I have decided, not to post anything on meta again. @rene

Comment: @Saswat alternatively, you could search before posting questions on meta -- as has been suggested to you previously. Or **just scroll down**. There were two other questions about this topic on the first page of meta.

Comment: You may not be worried about meta, but we're getting a little tired of seeing you post yet another question about a topic that's already been asked to death elsewhere. *That* is the reason for all the downvotes. It's sickening, not fun, to have to downvote and vote to close the same tired duplicate over and over again, but people do it because it's their duty.

Comment: Which post are you talking about which is asked to death before? @BoltClock

Comment: Well, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302329),, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302241), [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302244/shall-i-not-write-thanks-at-the-end-of-any-post), [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302132/why-did-my-points-get-reduced-after-i-started-a-bounty) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302263/) which had even been asked before [**by you**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296035). (to save @BoltClock time since I'm sure he's better things to do, and I'm bored).

Comment: Then what is the point in negating the posts on SO, even after rectifying or editing those posts? @TZHX

Comment: Your posts on SO are downvoted because you draw attention to them, and they tend to have numerous issues. Honestly, your attitude doesn't help -- you seem to be willfully immune to any feedback.

Comment: I heartily apologize if I sound rude, but I am just trying to gather knowledge on my ignorance. And today also, after people suggested me, I edited my question. Still there was three downvotes after modification. That's why I wonder what wrong did I do again? @TZHX

Comment: @Saswat And you did it again. Man you've got a pretty flat learning curve :-P ... Meta effect again, whining about (righteously) downvoted questions again. I was one of those _serial downvoters_ you suspect to spoil your rep. I was  targeting you by inspection of the quality of your questions. Though I'm not an expert regarding Java-script or PHP, I can well see many of your questions are low researched, and qualify you for help-vampireing as mentioned earlier. Same applies for your Meta SO questions IMHO, and also mentioned that on another closed Meta question you've asked recently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything you need should be in the question. If you can use Stack Snippets to demonstrate the problem then do so.

If you want to provide additional links that you think might make it easier for someone to help you such as a jsfiddle then feel free to add them too, but they are just that additional information.

One of the off-topic reasons is:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**...

So if you don't do that you run the risk of the question being closed on precisely those grounds. If you're lucky someone might add the code in the question itself instead but why run the risk?

Your aim is to get an answer to your question isn't it? If so bend over backwards to make it easy for someone to answer it. The harder your question is to answer the more likely potential answerers will just give up and move on to another better written question instead.

Comment: I am highly reluctant to edit code into a question from a jsfiddle or other site, simply out of respect for others' creative rights.  If they wanted it in, they would put it in or ask politely for help putting it in.  Putting code on SO grants a license and that is not a step a 3rd party is authorized to take without permission.

Comment: If it's a fiddle created by the asker of the question and it only contains a minimal demonstration of the issue I don't see that there's much of a problem. Most people don't bother though.

Comment: @Paul if you leave the link to the jsfiddle I see no issue with the creative rights / license issue...from the legal part on jsfiddle.net *All code belongs to the poster and no license is enforced.*

Comment: @rene The issue is moving code from jsfddle to SO.  All user-contributed text and code on SO is CC-BY-SA licensed.  I suspect the legal note on jsfiddle simply means that (i) code still belongs to whoever posted it, not jsfiddle; and (ii) jsfiddle will do nothing about anyone who copies content.  Which is good to know, if you were to post something there.  The copyright owner who posts a jsfiddle with a copyright notice / license can still pursue others who infringe... but this becomes a tiresome legal discussion best left to http://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm 100% with you on the last sentence (and I'm Ok with the rest). ;)

Answer (score 0):

OP, After looking at your link, I find that the code presented doesn't help with regards to the question. What you should do is provide ALL code that is relevant to the question which in your case would be the HTML code that produces the options. The less relevant code you provide, the lower chance you have of getting a great answer.