# Add Stack Snippet (Code Snippet) Documentation to Help Center and/or Editing Help

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, help-center, editing-help

I saw the new code snippet feature on the site and wanted to create one in an answer, but didn't see how. I expected to find the answer in the Editing Help, but didn't, so I went to the Help Center and searched for "snippet". I found nothing there, either.

Proper documentation is especially important for a new or evolving feature, because no one can be expected to know about it already. Please add documentation in the appropriate places. Mark the feature as "beta" or something if you want, but the feature not being finalized is actually an argument for, not against, documentation.

Comment: You also didn't find the [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) [posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0), I assume or were those your starting point?

Comment: @rene I found several meta posts but did not want to take the time sort them chronologically and read all of them to understand what the current behavior is. The posts you referenced are over a year old but I only started seeing this recently, so I suspect a lot has changed since then. Meta is not a substitute for official documentation of features.

Comment: I agree with that. We could create or change this question to a [tag:faq-proposed] if adding it to the help takes more than 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @rene I don't think a FAQ is appropriate. I should be in http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help where all the documentation is for the other editor features and also explained in greater depth in http://stackoverflow.com/help. See, for example, the help we have on [Syntax highlighting for code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) as well as [this Help Center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).