# Status of Stack Snippets 2.0: Are snippets now editable?

Tags: support, feature-request

The [meta post announcing Stack Snippets 2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) heralded the arrival of editable snippets.

This is exactly the feature I came searching for today here on meta. This sounds fantastic:

> Editable Snippets: When editing a question, a link will appear below the Snippet that you can click to re-launch the Snippet editor with your existing code. Upon closing the editor, changes will overwrite your existing Snippet markdown.

However, more than 1 year later, I don't see this feature in production, and searching has not revealed any additional information about what was put into production and when.

Could someone please update me?

---

**SOLUTION:**

Below the answer editor box, is either the text that Paulie_D describes, or there may be muted grey text: **show preview**. Click on `show preview`: the code will expand, and there, at the bottom of the expanded code, is the link to edit the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's available now.

Click on edit in the answer (or question) and the link is under the big blue button.

---

[image: Like this]

Comment: You asked about the status of the option...and it's clearly implemented. If you wish to discuss the actual implementation...that's another question.

Comment: Please don't edit this question...ask another. I have rolled your edit back.

Comment: i've already flagged it to the mods. You should ask a NEW question. Not broaden this one.