# Getting the URL of embedded Stack Snippet

Tags: discussion, support, stack-snippets

If someone embeds a Stack Snippet into Stack Overflow, is there a way I can get the Stack Snippet URL, so that I can share it and modify it etc?

Currently what I do is copy the code, go to JSFiddle and reorganize it, it's a lot of work, would be much nicer if I can take the Stack Snippet url.

Embedding example: **Shashank Agrawal** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636183/angularjs-scrollable-typeahead-input-field/38674791#38674791) to my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with *embeds a fiddle*. Do you have  a link of question/answer where this is the case?

Comment: @rene I updated my question, not sure if you call that embedding, feel free to edit my question if you use another term, basically I mean sharing a fiddle without providing the url

Comment: Ah, the old "genericized name" problem. Where "fiddle" is used to refer to anything with a similar look and feel to JSFiddle even if it doesn't bear the JSFiddle logo or domain.

Comment: @BoltClock missed that part, fixed now

Comment: I think you misread. My point is that the thing you're referring to is *not* JSFiddle, even though it looks and feels like it. It's called a Stack Snippet, an in-house product that has no relation to or affiliation with jsfiddle.net whatsoever.

Comment: Just share the whole post, I don't think there's any guarantee the mechanics will stay stable...

Comment: see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers?rq=1 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0?rq=1  tl;dr I normally copy the stack snippet to an answer and then play with it, if needed.

Comment: @BoltClock seriously? no offense, but it looks like either you stole the whole source code from them or they stole the whole source code from you! It looks the same, it feels the same, it functions the same, I swear I thought you use their API to integrate it on stackoverflow

Comment: well I like the way you edited the question though, it would be nice if stack snippets generates a url I can share or edit

Comment: @Lynob immediately under the answer there's a share button where you can share the answer, in this case http://stackoverflow.com/a/38674791/1675954

Comment: @RachelGallen I must admit, i never thought of it this way but the code cant be modified though