# Is it possible to link directly to a full-screen code snippet?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, code

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358027/1146608) is a thing of beauty. I want to share it far and wide, but I can't figure out how to link directly to the snippet in full screen mode. The helpful "Expand Snippet" button is great and pretty much exactly what I want, but it doesn't put a direct URL in the address bar.

Is it possible to link directly to a running code snippet, preferably in full screen or a stand-alone editor like https://codepen.io/pen/ or https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: You can create a codepen/jsfiddle and link to it, but there's no way to set a snippet to open in fullscreen

Comment: This is by no means a dealbreaker for this feature request, but I would suggest that if the Stack Exchange team chooses to support this, it should open the full-page snippet in a domain other than `stackoverflow.com` and/or with a more prominent "This is a Stack Snippet!" header, to avoid spoofing the Stack Overflow site itself (e.g., a [full-screen snippet that looks exactly like Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269791/710446), on `stackoverflow.com`, that harvests passwords from unsuspecting users)

Comment: That is amazing @apsillers, thanks for sharing.

Comment: One of the many features suggested as part of the initial feedback here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right now, no. There is not even a way to generate a link directly to the snippet either.

The results of a snipped are hosted inside an `<iframe>`, but there is no fixed url based on any identifiable information.

Clicking the run button just transmits your code to https://stacksnippets.net/js as a POST call.

[image]

The service doesn't generate a unique url for your snippet, so you're out of luck unless you want to re-send all of the source code.

Comment: You could use a JavaScript URI to do the post request on a per case basis, and even use compression to reduce the length of the URI, getting people to click such a link would be the hard part.

Comment: Even if it's a POST?

Comment: Yeah, using an AJAX request to post the data. I'm on my phone right now or I would make up a demo. Maybe later.

Comment: Just use a URL shortener! Oh wait, then you'll have two problems…

Comment: ... but the bit ain't one