# How should I improve a question I have asked which hasn't received much attention?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I asked this question [Is there a way to centralize a card in a container using materialize CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71743065) regarding a CSS framework, but I felt it was less interesting to users as it hasn't received much attention. I later realised it might not be a problem on my own part but that of the CSS framework which I'm using which was unmaintained and riddled with bugs.

So how do I improve my question to find more answers from users?

Comment: I am not familiar with this technology and so can't give a specific answer, other than for you to apply a bounty if/when you gain more rep, but I always like this type of meta question

Comment: There are a lot of classes referenced without definition, there's an app.js file that's referenced too. Are those necessary to understanding and answering the problem or not?

Comment: Those classes are necessary, as I said am using a framework so all the CSS classes are in the framework, or if I can get your point I should not givevide redundant infos (app.js)

Comment: Okay @HovercraftFullOfEels I will do just that in my subsequent questions

Comment: First thing you could do to improve the post is to add a runnable snippet [SME here, btw]

Comment: Other than that, it is an O.K. question with a reasonable issue with at least two solutions.

Comment: So @OlegValteriswithUkraine the [sme] helps to find subject matter expert pertaining to the field. Concerning the snippets can I also add runnable snippets that links to a site if possible?

Comment: What I mean it is the [sme] is it a tag I can add to my question like python, Linux e.t.c to find relative expert in such subject

Comment: And the snippets u where referring to I saw it in action when I viewed the code later on. It was helpful.

Comment: Ah, that. No, @geek, this would be considered a meta tag (and those are not allowed). We get over 5000 questions a day, so most posts spend very little time on the home page and simply go unnoticed due to sheer volume.

Comment: it has two upvotes and an answer so  it is a good question , with some topic it can take some time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I felt it was less interesting to users as it hasn't received much attention

Not necessarily. Stack Overflow at this point is *massive*. We get an unmanageable number of questions daily while the supply of subject matter experts is quite limited. Just take a look at the results of the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1588478#graph) on questions posted last month to gauge the issue:

[image: trend of questions to answers from April 7th to May 7th 2022]

This means everything between the upper (questions) and lower (answers) bound  did not get an answer, not even taking into account the fact that the distribution of answers is far from being equal: easy questions in popular tags can get dozens of answers in the first hours of being posted while complex issues or posts in relatively obscure tags can go unanswered for ages.

And then there is a problem of having enough subject matter experts following the main tag ([materialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/materialize) in your case) and being active on the main site in general (for example, I provided the answer to your question only because I saw this Meta post). With [only 3540](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/materialize/topusers) all-time questions at the time of this writing, it is a *relatively* niche tag.

---

> how do I improve my question to find more answers from users?

First of all, you need to ensure the post is properly tagged to reach the correct audience. Albeit, for the most part, your post was tagged correctly, the [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forms) tag was irrelevant (and could cut off a portion of experts not interested in forms).

Secondly, since your question is concerned with one aspect of the HTML / CSS / JS trinity, you could use a runnable Stack Snippet to make the issue easily reproducible by others (you can learn more about Stack Snippets [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270944/11407695)).

Finally, you could fix a couple of editorial issues (like proper capitalization of the framework name) to make the post easier to visually parse. Other than that, your post looked fine, so I fixed all of the mentioned issues for you.

---

**On the issue of Materialize CSS**

This framework is actively maintained by open-source community since the original team abandoned the project some time ago. You can find the up-to-date documentation on the framework [here](https://materializecss.github.io/) and the source repository [here](https://github.com/materializecss/materialize). There is currently a [motion](https://github.com/materializecss/materialize/discussions/263) for contacting the original contributors if you are interested.

---

**P. S.** You did good by posting on Meta about how to improve your question — if the   post in discussion is on-topic and of at least decent quality, such requests are generally welcomed by the community at large. However, please do not, following the positive outcome of this post, make it a habit to fast-track questions that have not received answers by making a post on Meta.

Also, if you feel like you need another pair of eyes on a given post, you can always drop by to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to a relevant chat room and ask for help / review there (make sure you read room rules first, though, as chat rooms usually have a specific topic and might not accept review requests).

Comment: I still find the Question (on SO) difficult to read, with still too many Typos and Grammar Mistakes... ("*in[ ]correctly*" + "*except*" (= "expect"...?) + "*a[n] erratic*" + "*been*" (x2) + "*the other left space been bogus*" which doesn't really make sense to me (especially "*other*" (= "outer"...?) + "*bogus*" (sounds a bit strange in a Technical Thread...))...

Comment: @chivracq yeah, I honestly failed to find a way to reword the last part so I left it be for someone else to edit (maybe Peter will change by)

Comment: Yeah-yeah, I was just giving my Feedback, I saw you had already improved the Content and Layout/Formatting... But I know for myself I quickly get "annoyed" if I have to read 5 times a Question or even just a single Sentence before being "sure" I (hopefully) understand what the Asker meant exactly...

Comment: @chivracq not that I mind the feedback :) Was just noting back that yeah, I definitely did not fix everything (writing up 2 posts in a row on a weekend is a bit taxing) - might get back to it to finish the job a bit later.

Comment: Well, my "Feedback" was actually rather meant for @OP, and I "originally" wanted to post it as a Comment to the Qt, but you had then posted this Answer which already addressed a few Points I wanted to mention, so I decided to post my Comment as a "Complement" to your Answer... (Maybe I should have started my 1st Comment with a "+" to indicate that I was adding a few Points to your Answer...)

Comment: The last data point does not look credible. It looks like partially missing data,

Comment: Do you refer to the last week, @PeterMortensen? SEDE will flush tomorrow, this is why there is a drop (if I understood you correctly) - I'll be happy to update the screenshot once te clock strikes midnight UTC.