# Is there a description of the policy for links in posts?

Tags: support

Edit: I just want to know if there is an "official" policy for links to code, or any links, for that matter.

--------------------- (posted earlier:)

I was wondering if there is an upper limit to the lines of code that I can post on Stack Overflow. Apparently, if someone posts a link to jsfiddle.net without any code, the following error message is generated:

```
Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.
```

What happens if I post too many lines of code? Is there an amount of code in a post that is considered "too much"? Is there an explicit description of the policy regarding the links and the amount of code posted? I looked under the help link but could not find anything.

Comment: You should provide us with the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. If you have to ask whether or not you have too much code, then you already know your answer. You do.

Comment: Yes but my question was if there is a explicit policy description. You only referred to a part of my post (Which was to give an example, not the main question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to know if there is an "official" policy for links to code, or any links, for that matter.

That error message is not telling you not to post links, it's telling you that if your question needs a jsfiddle to be useful, it almost certainly needs inline code to be useful.

From the Close reasons:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you're giving us a link to jsfiddle—or ideone or pastebin or any other external resource for active or passive code—then you're almost certainly looking for help with that code, and you haven't included that code.

---

Why isn't the external link enough? Well, consider that your external link may go down. Or someone might not trust you enough to click a random link in your question. Or, with some sites, links aren't versioned; you could easily edit the external code and make it irrelevant to the question. And so on. See the answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269253/no-jsfiddle-without-code-rule-is-too-harsh) for more explanation.

---

What's so special about jsfiddle? Nothing. It's just the most popular place to post external code in questions that should, but don't, have inline code, so the developers chose to add a test for it. There have been suggestions to add other sites, and as far as I know, nobody has any argument against doing so in principle, it's just that most of them would only help a handful of questions and therefore might not be worth doing.

(Well, I suppose that since jsfiddle covers almost the exact same cases as the built-in [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers), that might make it special in some way…)

---

> What happens if I post too many lines of code? Is there an amount of code in a post that is considered "too much"?

No. The right amount of code is always *all of it*—and all of the input, too.

But note that it's all of the code *from your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example*, not your whole application.

(This also means that when people say "I can't post the code because it's proprietary corporate code", they're missing the point. The MCVE they create to demonstrate their problem is not proprietary—or, if it is, they shouldn't be asking on SO in the first place.)

Comment: The Stack Snippets concept seems awesome-I just tried it out. You can run the code and test it before you post. The only thing I wish it had is to save a draft and return to it later. I guess you could tinker with your code elsewhere and post it on SO when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

This should clarify things:

```js
function clickedYes(){ alert('good job!');}
function clickedNo(){ alert('shame on you!');}
```

```html
Do you always post all of your code?
<button id='ButtonYes' onclick="clickedYes()">Yes</button>
<button id='ButtonNo' onclick="clickedNo()">No</button>
```