# Should Code Snippets be reengineered like fiddles?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-snippets

I was lately considering that a great deal of JavaScript questions on Stack Overflow can be easily solved by reproducing the issue in tools like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com).

Generally speaking, since JavaScript has the ability to run directly into a browser, I automatically create a fiddle to reproduce the issue. Finding solutions with those tools is much easier, instead of thinking in terms of language syntax or OOP capabilities in certain instances.

Additionally, those threads are created by developers with limited knowledge of programming languages, thus the best way to show them is by creating a visual context.

---

***The issues:***

- Code Snippets are limited compared to external tools.
- Don't provide libraries support.
- Cannot add versioning of the same script when answering.

---

***Question:***

Unlike other programming languages JavaScript have the ability and tools to run directly into the browser.

To this end, **why doesn't Stack Overflow provide a fiddle-like functionality to JavaScript/jQuery-related questions?**

---

***Related questions:***

*[Should JavaScript questions be down-voted for not providing JSFiddles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267640/should-javascript-questions-be-down-voted-for-not-providing-jsfiddles)*

*[Asking for a fiddle in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265210/asking-for-a-fiddle-in-comments)*

Comment: Are you serious? This was rolled out a long time ago with great fanfare.

Comment: Seriously? Code snippets are limited, nothing like the tools I've mentioned.

Comment: You've mentioned nothing that code snippets don't do.

Comment: If you have some specific features you'd like to be added to the Stack Snippets functionality, then you need to spell out in detail **exactly what you want to see added**. Right now, your question is incredibly vague and it's not at all clear what you want out of it that's not already there. Afaik, they're planning to add support for libraries. Your other two bullet points frankly make no sense.

Comment: Frankly, I was asking out of curiosity. I'm not looking for any features added. I searched and didn't find an answer. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @carlodurso It sounds like you do want features added to code snippets (for instance, library support and versioning). You could have asked your question as "Can code snippets support..." Or do you want the SE developers to start the feature over from scratch?

Comment: Thanks David. Initially, I didn't even consider _Code Snippets_ in my question because I thought that fiddles provide a better experience in terms of usability. I think that _Code Snippets_ should be re-engineered.

Answer (score 9):

```js
alert('That would be a pretty cool feature!');
```

See also [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for more information.

Comment: thanks Jason, but as far as I understand code snippets are pretty limited in their capabilities. Not to mention that most users link to fiddles.

Comment: @carlodurso This is the fiddle-*like* functionality you requested. For situations where something even *more* fiddle-like is required, there is JSFiddle.